# while i try to run in iOS 6 my code throws Sen test Framework error. why?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios-simulator, ios6, xcode4.5

I have a project that is developed in `iOS 5.0` and now i need to update my project to `iOS 6.0` .
While doing this my `xcode 4.5` throws the error as below...

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/SenTestingKit.framework/Versions/A/SenTestingKit
  Referenced from: /Users/developer/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/6EFF12B6-DA80-4DD8-B3CF-B217C5EA63DF/XxxxXxxx.app/xxxxXxxxXxx
  Reason: image not found
```

still it runs and works perfectly in `iOS 5` devices and i am trying to run this app in `iphone Simulator iOS  6.0` it throws that error...
Any body have any idea about this...
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to delete the derived Data, then clean the project and restart Xcode.
If its still not working, check the Target dependencies of your library.

It seams like it has Problems with the armv7s Architecture, check that in the
Buildsettings of your Framework!

Comment: see the answer i made, i think this is it!

Comment: Please look at Mathew's answer to understand the error reason and how to clear it.

Answer (score 20):

[image]

its working....set SentestingKit.framework as optional

Comment: This got my app rejected in the MAS because of a "loosely linked framework"

Answer (score 5):

@fry copied his answer from here:

http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/xcode/260066-sentesttingkit-framework-runtime-failure.html

There's more information there which I found useful in solving this problem.