# exited abnormally with signal 5: Trace/BPT trap: 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, xcode4.5, authorize.net

I developed an application which runs on iphone 4 and 4s . but in iphone 3GS and iphone 5. when installed application crashes when opened . Below is i am getting on console.can any one help me

```
Incident Identifier: 8219A707-BE9E-4D61-B5CD-96482EE0EBB7
CrashReporter Key:   e239ed78545d04387be2d657c27c88568ecd65f4
Hardware Model:      iPhone2,1
Process:         MH_Canvas [356]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/7B7C3BF6-14FD-47C9-895A-D09A52455EDC/MH_Canvas.app/MH_Canvas
Identifier:      MH_Canvas
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-06-04 11:04:36.525 +0530
OS Version:      iOS 6.1.2 (10B146)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000000e7ffdefe
Crashed Thread:  0

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /Developer/Library/Frameworks/SenTestingKit.framework/SenTestingKit
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/7B7C3BF6-14FD-47C9-895A-D09A52455EDC/MH_Canvas.app/MH_Canvas
  Reason: image not found
  Dyld Version: 212.3.1

Binary Images:
   0x1e000 -    0x65fff +MH_Canvas armv7  <815a467178f630f2b09e449600945602> /var/mobile/Applications/7B7C3BF6-14FD-47C9-895A-D09A52455EDC/MH_Canvas.app/MH_Canvas
0x2fecc000 - 0x2feecfff  dyld armv7  <454baf45f9a831aa88e1ea4447c58d4e> /usr/lib/dyld
0x33453000 - 0x33539fff  AVFoundation armv7  <320761e836883aeabf3cb5c53edb636d> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x34270000 - 0x343a2fff  CoreFoundation armv7  <fcb8d4e838543bcb9a52c9f232b8b4eb> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x360f5000 - 0x36134fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <410d69b356e533d6a1d538cf33059634> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x3c271000 - 0x3c31efff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <28dcf6ee713b387ebb763d11d4b3cd37> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Let us see what is there in the crash report at `/var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/Canvassing_2013-06-05-163333_iPhone.plist`

Comment: can u tell me how to see that

Comment: Finder ->GO -> GO to folder ->Enter the path

Comment: Please edit the question and add the log there.Edit button is at bottom of question

Comment: I just had a similar problem and it was because one of the frameworks that I was using was incompatible with iOS 7.

Comment: [This SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855389/how-to-symbolicate-crash-log-xcode) helped me to figure out the exact crash on my code and fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The crashlog says you didnt add the `SenTestingKit.framework` properly. Check whether it is added properly as said in its docs

Comment: i have included senTestingKit.framework properly but i didnt import it anywhere in my application

Comment: then i shouldnot run in all iphone right . why its only in iphone 5 and 3GS

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13010038/while-i-try-to-run-in-ios-6-my-code-throws-sen-test-framework-error-why

Comment: i did sentestingkit.framework as Optional nw i send build to my friend and tell u whether its working or not. thanx .

Comment: @LithuT.V, I'm getting the same error but its for XCTest.framework, I've already asked a seperate question too. What I want to know is I don't want to add test cases with my app. So do I still need to have this framework added to my app? Here's my question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31028228/app-is-crashing-after-successfully-compile-and-build-in-xcode). Thanks!