# How to analysis crash in Xcode6?

Tags: ios, crash, xcode6

I found crash logs but I can't understand it. I tried from this:[How to symbolicate crash log Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855389/how-to-symbolicate-crash-log-xcode-6) but I got stuck in seme step because of I haven't use crash logs before.
Then I pull the log into a folder and then rename it because it contains chinese. And I tried follow this:http://www.juliusparishy.com/articles/symbolicating-ios-8-crash-logs. It didn't work also.

```
applematoMacBook-Air:crash apple$ DEVELOPER_DIR=`xcode-select -print-path` /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DTDeviceKitBase.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash -o ./myapp-resymbolicated.crash ./MoneyPower.crash ./MoneyPower.app.dSYM
No crash report version in ./MoneyPower.crash at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DTDeviceKitBase.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash line 957.
```

Below is the log:

```
Incident Identifier: 13C0A1CB-2A40-496D-9DEF-DE85F72B84DE
CrashReporter Key:   52577145db78209ce4892c3e02465b6cfdc27b07
Hardware Model:      iPhone5,4
OS Version:          iPhone OS 8.1 (12B411)
Kernel Version:      Darwin Kernel Version 14.0.0: Tue Oct  7 00:04:37 PDT 2014; root:xnu-    2783.3.13~4/RELEASE_ARM_S5L8950X
Date:                2014-11-26 16:57:11 +0800
Time since snapshot: 65 ms

Free pages:                              2758
Active pages:                            16544
Inactive pages:                          7324
Speculative pages:                       759
Throttled pages:                         170016
Purgeable pages:                         0
Wired pages:                             33684
File-backed pages:                       23985
Anonymous pages:                         642
Compressions:                            714623
Decompressions:                          224424
Compressor Size:                         29519
Uncompressed Pages in Compressor:        71670
Page Size:                               4096
Largest process:   kbd
Processes
 Name       |            <UUID>                |     CPU Time|     rpages|       purgeable| recent_max| lifetime_max| fds |  [reason]         | (state)

AppleIDAuthAgent <e05ab3faa1243f3a900bac613820c3cd>         0.158         216                0           -          1257   50                       (daemon) (idle)
          cplogd <8e9ff218b5de30428df98e6d088cc6e7>         0.122         116                0           -           457   50                       (daemon) (idle)
             ind <35c1864a720232ea9b42aeb1df454ac6>         0.420         360                0           -          1221   50                       (daemon) (idle)
MailCompositionS <fb46b62148b432bca350f4f0962e5baa>         2.197        4089                0           -          4928   50                       (suspended)
     QSInstaller <0ac1afc270963cba8e7ceacfbd88327b>         0.796         401                0           -          1983   50                       (daemon) (idle)
    Eudic_Pro_us <c767d73448bd38f381ef61e8059487f0>        59.839        5178                0           -         12422   50                       (suspended)
CloudKeychainPro <bf2dc17596d9381bb02f0d3848253d29>         0.264         123                0           -           376   50                       (daemon) (idle)
         rocketd <379e73e3ec7b395296a9185cdb886153>         0.025          67                0           -           158   50                       (daemon) (idle)
      TingIPhone <fead8493c4d53af88370a65b90c8e13e>         2.015        2293                0           -          8027   50                       (suspended)
MessagesNotifica <c21e17f099763f079a8909e53939cab6>         1.292        1609                0           -          3871   50                       (suspended)
IMDPersistenceAg <8709c1b2c8ac37c38331026019487c4a>         1.948         444                0           -          4001   50                       (daemon) (idle)
           QZone <bad24b7fc2e33bc7ad0f9e35fe56fcdc>        53.227        8769                0           -         17340  100                       (suspended)
            adid <318b35f544ef30458c779f196840141b>         0.187         118                0           -           528   50                       (daemon) (idle)
com.apple.facebo <0aa3451928ec326781922890b85b6376>         0.418         357                0           -          1324   50                       (daemon) (idle)
  MicroMessenger <5d0e48e5bb623e088cb372a1981d09cd>        31.297        6579                0           -         17535  100                       (suspended)
coresymbolicatio <015dae53431f3f89a557a3f1ed748ba1>         0.103          82                0           -           187   50                       (daemon) (idle)
     diagnosticd <4593765ed9a833228e3f1515308b20fa>         0.443         121                0           -           254   50                       (daemon) (idle)
AssetCacheLocato <6018ec37b6ad3dde8cb6d576b24b61e7>         0.473         235                0           -           849   50                       (daemon) (idle)
com.apple.Stream <7b86d693c03f3149a1eba23d4d834eeb>        27.701         161                0           -           739   50                       (daemon) (idle)
CallHistorySyncH <8ce6f70f70273829936775ea5cccdd12>         1.824         428                0           -          1225   50                       (daemon) (idle)
            fmfd <eb696bfb4c03371b83b1f4e89e446eeb>         1.826         422                0           -          1348   50                       (daemon) (idle)
     cloudphotod <2edd5622cf23381f8b22c92bc4b7a5c3>         6.342         617                0           -          1752   50                       (daemon) (idle)
CacheDeleteGeoTi <bb953149b86a33cf8cc9226b9a74bd34>         0.196         146                0           -           562   50                       (daemon) (idle)
    mobileassetd <9a378084bd953954a1dd760d49fe7ede>         2.244         392                0           -          1792   50                       (daemon) (idle)
            geod <48710d774a42357ea97f9ad0a527ee5f>         4.365         635                0           -          1434   50                       (daemon) (idle)
CacheDeleteAppCo <ee9139b8e1db3d3ba6d20a08a2cf08ac>         9.867         343                0           -          1226   50                       (daemon) (idle)
CacheDeleteMobil <9cbeda33d15f3ee4af73660e85b8a738>         0.416         345                0           -          1489   50                       (daemon) (idle)
CacheDeleteITune <9b54c0dcf93a3ddfa5f461436ea11664>         0.436         185                0           -           815   50                       (daemon) (idle)
         deleted <11e9a7b04fd335f5ac6e6f9e7922deff>         0.278         153                0           -           395   50                       (daemon) (idle)
   rtcreportingd <6a3478eeeec93f1797f432895851613a>         1.912         349                0           -          1129   50                       (daemon) (idle)
       SOHUVideo <8f2a763084bd33df91fb4d49bec096ce>      1039.212        5915                0           -         11547  100                       (suspended)
           vvebo <d76cf63bb0543b75b0f28e0ddc9bfe39>       439.540       13452                0           -         21578  200                       (suspended)
       pipelined <75d09f2b0b493a2d84a7043a5ce96360>         0.524         346                0           -          1858   50                       (daemon) (idle)
      librariand <72539244d3923f2d88cd15d9ce08c0bc>         0.601         243                0           -           859   50                       (daemon) (idle)
com.apple.Stream <7b86d693c03f3149a1eba23d4d834eeb>         2.964         138                0           -           555   50                       (daemon) (idle)
            swcd <09d4cfa1662e3483b7da852d10cf45d5>         0.108         163                0           -           548   50                       (daemon) (idle)
   findmydeviced <2b7e318bab4e394ebd19a17ed0bf979d>         0.843         530                0           -          1786   50                       (daemon) (idle)
      aosnotifyd <16ece00586ec3ccab1fbdeb6d92aad1a>         1.598         495                0           -          1741   50                       (daemon) (idle)
mobile_installat <9c9425ce271b3154b99d23e6e35240ef>        18.061         360                0           -          1213   50                       (daemon) (idle)
streaming_zip_co <f8a43feeded33f30ae10bafafde0f052>         1.787         224                0           -           960   50                       (daemon) (idle)
ContainerMetadat <24e851abc8b43f4093ea6d80c5a262ac>        29.550         488                0           -          1963   50                       (daemon) (idle)
        QSCenter <00f1d456fc583c9a8c2c57ecd3327f46>       238.360        1344                0           -          5462  200                       (daemon) (idle)
   familycircled <5fea61a5086f36348233dbf09e7adeee>         0.521         397                0           -          1481   50                       (daemon) (idle)
        AppStore <4443338ecbfe3b85afc4aba498d0cee8>       138.361       24407                0           -         25261  100                       (suspended)
            misd <8ea26d6e019d355795ff0cb117733f68>         0.258         159                0           -           747   50                       (daemon) (idle)
     Preferences <6bcd6b5ca2393131902eaee019857bd2>        27.053        5010                0           -          8509   50                       (suspended)
     MQQSecureJB <019bc764bc133db7baafa8a23c9445e7>         2.767        2271                0           -          7357   50                       (suspended)
         healthd <8495258d6e7b3ecfa21c18dc110b5402>         2.035         412                0           -          1099   50                       (daemon) (idle)
        BlueTool <79ec82b9ee3b31e7aee4ad348206fb07>         0.085         112                0           -           452   50                       (daemon) (idle)
        nehelper <d3804c7b0ccf3e1aa437061c7229cfb7>         1.580         217                0           -           843   50                       (daemon) (idle)
      BTLEServer <666685c2f90a3daa81bbe6520a811206>         0.326         273                0           -          1629   50                       (daemon) (idle)
        recentsd <04f80416cfc734cc8f3d6be6578467e0>         1.223         530                0           -          1583   50                       (daemon) (idle)
   medialibraryd <c80a6cacc2a334729705adb044e68c00>         9.229         563                0           -          1479   50                       (daemon) (idle)
      DTMobileIS <2a11eaaf903d38798629d3aecd137832>       302.687         502                0           -          1976   50                       (daemon) (idle)
storebookkeeperd <046122091101309d968c43a2be97867c>         3.857         954                0           -          2460   50                       (daemon) (idle)
    itunesstored <651906971d0732e1942355da4bd91100>       110.578        2312                0           -          4746  100                       (daemon) (idle)
    itunescloudd <47bdc6fbccd6364480dbd1a2b3c7998d>         5.967         859                0           -          2625   50                       (daemon) (idle)
    CMFSyncAgent <268f03103f6032af8597e9fce57491b7>         0.152         143                0           -           498   50                       (daemon) (idle)
WirelessRadioMan <40bc5fa762323e69a45d77854a53c4b2>         2.835         246                0           -           931   50                       (daemon) (idle)
            awdd <857efa30f8e23d2a9f25f53673af6ccb>         3.726         520                0           -          1124   50                       (daemon) (idle)
           passd <cea683659ba036a6a6f4b4f927160353>        30.283         679                0           -          2519   50                       (daemon) (idle)
 lsuseractivityd <9057065ea9cd37e2b905cfa169f62ef2>         3.083         384                0           -          1773   50                       (daemon) (idle)
         assetsd <55f3adbf8b1e3bf3b57471e01356417c>        38.141        1611                0           -          4256   50                       (daemon) (idle)
   webbookmarksd <3173c4f369ac382aa0e03975b1f6bc18>        26.917         564                0           -          1458   50                       (daemon) (idle)
       QSCharmer <b7f401ca48cd3c13a7e6a51328d183e8>        17.301         819                0           -          2277  100                       (daemon) (idle)
        profiled <4edd7c7d0a8631b58e739cfd13fc1865>         6.793         547                0           -          4488   50                       (daemon) (idle)
     GoodReader4 <dbe6961a764b347abbd609b6a223e6a7>         4.941        2008                0           -          5229   50                       (suspended)
        misagent <716ddd8b8fdf30a180872e0ac95b0c96>         1.161         129                0           -           526   50                       (daemon) (idle)
   nsurlstoraged <2216f383497435919d46cce44e2750dd>        23.292        1352                0           -          2999  200                       (daemon) (idle)
networkd_privile <1c19249e1c9b3c1fae4bdb06671795d0>         0.986          92                0           -           261   50                       (daemon) (idle)
        routined <014344942eca323bb12d360e06c8d865>        13.554         511                0           -          2147   50                       (daemon) (idle)
         keybagd <30eb49ca086937f4a52413bee502a025>         4.062         110                0           -           328   50                       (daemon) (idle)
      assistantd <bbc6396ded9f32f89e4f3c3c62550786>         1.593         464                0           -          1793   50                       (daemon) (idle)
             pkd <d1ef96d5c84a3ec7bac8811f210d0d86>         8.705         335                0           -           886   50                       (daemon) (idle)
       revisiond <e89e877ac57239f59c0eed4ea5ecdff9>         1.206         267                0           -           569   50                       (daemon) (idle)
com.baidu.ime.Ba <2518403a187230cc98feadecab0d1a63>        13.933        1975                0           -          7508   50                       (suspended)
MobileGestaltHel <069f2f40d7ee3345adcc53637ae9ddf7>         3.302         173                0           -           597   50                       (daemon) (idle)
        sandboxd <a2a6b1bb1b3231af96cf6125c8f3e971>         0.722         144                0           -           620   50                       (daemon) (idle)
DuetHeuristic-BM <003d26850d5e3dc7997d444a182c03ad>         5.482         327                0           -          1031   50                       (daemon) (idle)
       coreduetd <ac84ea2f95a43b9e911738284359db9b>       270.000        1370                0           -          2466   50                       (daemon) (idle)
           timed <3b91fa8cbe9131af958b430e85fa448d>         5.483         247                0           -          1002   50                       (daemon) (idle)
       accountsd <6185caa9f3793aef892ccf0ec3391ced>        80.564        1225                0           -          3233   50                       (daemon) (idle)
      calaccessd <9d8bb08b0f1d33a3878f213805bb7a14>        38.640         734                0           -          1799   50                       (daemon) (idle)
  mobactivationd <04a28566ff493e2b931706a59270fe8a>         3.647         207                0           -           814   50                       (daemon) (idle)
       securityd <d425cdb8afb13ccd836a8e0e706f33e0>        79.635        1033                0           -          2432   50                       (daemon) (idle)
containermanager <7d4e114c087f3566bb0fe4be34f0d315>        18.437         336                0           -           880   50                       (daemon) (idle)
         lockbot <ba949fe90d403a95abc20b3780e5dfab>         1.286         176                0           -           676   50                       (daemon) (idle)
   nsurlsessiond <7676f54e86233a47b73b7a707f5903e1>       181.227         870                0           -          2165   50                       (daemon)
           gamed <424e1a60719830b5b4d799ed01954180>        13.246         979                0           -          3083   50                       (daemon)
           Music <8c00f2c612d631bca8c94cb80079f45e>        10.284        1793                0           -          4795   50                       (background)
            absd <84d31e794d8b345bbdc06c990e18922d>         0.218          97                0           -           386   50                       (daemon)
            bird <1c0b6b6474ab3b0686ca1fbcd547245d>        37.934        1711                0           -          3450   50                       (daemon)
          cloudd <309d7860b8db331a978c2c814f0c8332>       108.050        1442                0           -          3031   50                       (daemon)
notification_pro <6ceb017d382139b19f49e20e461dbee2>         2.658         189                0           -           368   50                       (daemon)
            afcd <9725b438ad9d3e259a2e628f6fffb449>         0.265         139                0           -           294   50                       (daemon)
mobile_assertion <de75b4d90658347b8873a4938aa02122>         0.117         119                0           -           340   50                       (daemon)
      MobileMail <7285623db1753882bca1a7983ba6a479>        10.635        1433                0           -          3853   50                       (resume) (continuous)
       MobileSMS <e36c461c698438948d233a751658dc8d>        12.979        2795                0           -          7633   50                       (continuous)
             lsd <b4acbcce51273ae699bcdaba19e8e6d2>        31.574         615                0           -          1453   50                       (daemon)
            tccd <046fa98e4bfd30789c10447b04d67a59>        11.467         307                0           -           904   50                       (daemon)
             kbd <91b2e4707a4233c598ba51ab8d765fc6>        89.667       31706                0           -         32409   50      [highwater]      (daemon)
   InCallService <d83952575cf631baac492f39dd5bd2c5>         6.497        1132                0           -          3379   50                       (resume) (continuous)
        FaceTime <d0e139af986b34d08c219f8057708b23>         6.179        1517                0           -          4518   50                       (continuous)
      MoneyPower <c72bab945b653b7cb101e44f88e4d1ff>         1.352        1726                0           -          4493   50                       (frontmost) (resume)
            ptpd <1b2175128a1e3880bc9f2c8835df0a84>         0.899         871                0           -          1789   50                       (daemon)
        BTServer <8138d14a265f3445a288e8a8fefc4f88>         4.663         590                0           -          2360   50                       (daemon)
           amfid <0162233147ee3429bd1e344fde40d8d7>         0.023          76                0           -           173   25                       (daemon) (idle)
      discoveryd <8aed6e4ba09f3761b12796bc1ef045d7>       104.080         900                0           -          1818  100                       (daemon)
           wifid <07a9fb4965473001880a56f4e06e18c8>        52.415         538                0           -          1545   50                       (daemon)
       lockdownd <0d55399f17293f74af1f04987c0c7f30>        67.031         401                0           -          1410   50                       (daemon)
         imagent <c0ef36357e8c3658b3876bfb5dd25996>        12.568         805                0           -          2623   50                       (daemon)
identityservices <d4c29d99664e34bdb82e046c600271c1>        18.707         713                0           -          2183   50                       (daemon)
         syslogd <d9a9a4a03dea32d8b041d5ac197c8f98>        46.064         344                0           -           445   50                       (daemon)
   iaptransportd <4d6f8290631a33928f87ddf2cc87ac41>         8.753         318                0           -           821   50                       (daemon)
    mediaserverd <88151824720a3e649461c81e73cd4b5e>      2173.885        6721                0           -         32721   50                       (daemon)
       locationd <48b400c62e4c394299e6124935dedf08>       644.756        1671                0           -          4824  100                       (daemon)
          powerd <7d9c31f8a70431a884047612f65e1c02>        32.568         250                0           -           515   50                       (daemon)
            apsd <4b5d193860a43c96af1313e8128ede6d>        37.354         638                0           -          1869   50                       (daemon)
        networkd <33404341f70c3231a60f0b40bbe968d7>       141.706         771                0           -          1791   50                       (daemon)
     dataaccessd <189b8330160434f8b5b0ebee43290697>        10.081         862                0           -          2432   50                       (daemon)
             vmd <9d324b2ab0b03b93bdc165c1cc27e9d1>         0.442         266                0           -           859   50                       (daemon)
        sharingd <79def39dbceb3b9190742c7bbcd0ad7c>        12.374         726                0           -          2495   50                       (daemon)
    mediaremoted <4f8bff5ccf923657b17f72dd2b002f1c>        67.387         316                0           -          1282   50                       (daemon)
        SCHelper <196af7bc7205305082beae63d0143af9>         2.662         116                0           -           318   50                       (daemon)
             atc <a4bf959671773746b408f825460ac0aa>        22.413        1425                0           -          3760   50                       (daemon)
    syslog_relay <1ce514e7b1cb39218a1bb4afb37a2a47>         1.200         111                0           -           275   50                       (daemon)
        installd <acf9113478133a9d8ec90eb3233a0d4e>        57.496         488                0           -          2140   50                       (daemon)
     SpringBoard <a4cf2abe291e3c9082c58d38b9cf0356>       709.123       10136                0           -         27546  100                      
      backboardd <d35acdc51c0e39da896d8760d30f72ff>      2534.389        7304                0           -          6100   50                       (daemon)
    fairplayd.H2 <30cc265b9aa13511a461149ecf326b4e>        22.379         236                0           -          1404   50                       (daemon)
         configd <287504687f22353fb98df72ce0445f85>        87.054         478                0           -          1256   50                       (daemon)
       fseventsd <533f5fbbb6683b86bbce8649a74eb688>        30.630         529                0           -          1031   50                       (daemon)
  UserEventAgent <f2ea7b62ae4e38ffa9c7b5a93c5dc6dc>       328.253         880                0           -          2494  200                       (daemon)
      assertiond <36cbbe6205723972844d2a3a61e5c31d>        26.361         356                0           -          1013   50                       (daemon)
       distnoted <11db066ae1fa32dfb4755accfe8d6f32>        14.823         237                0           -           472   50                       (daemon)
   wirelessproxd <b480891c9ec93154bbe2107ea7e96abf>         2.202         210                0           -           912   50                       (daemon)
discoveryd_helpe <099460d32af7337d95d6362993ea1406>         0.285         140                0           -           588   50                       (daemon)
filecoordination <6d9f3fb4ccf630eb8ccba96e51cb1bbe>         4.758         321                0           -           880  100                       (daemon)
      aggregated <04c00c9ea92a3b40a1221b7b622e9d1c>      1171.560        1131                0           -          2725   50                       (daemon)
   callservicesd <ae5546b18df13320a52bcf46c9dc1a65>         2.751         606                0           -          1597   50                       (daemon)
             ubd <89ad1cd20dbb32eab266903379256adb>         0.238         214                0           -           770   50                       (daemon)
     touchsetupd <a08d390378a433979da5ce42197b1189>         0.759         193                0           -           731   50                       (daemon)
       gputoolsd <956b542f7d263b38a6384d8aa8e5760a>         0.289         735                0           -          2089   50                       (daemon)
MobileStorageMou <605984d05a1c30ada9bb32338673ea00>         0.072         129                0           -           375   50                       (daemon)
        cfprefsd <1a4938a6a60e3d7ba5e940f96033c6c8>        33.537         455                0           -           897   50                       (daemon)
      CommCenter <552a7fd4f67e32ceb6fa3f1664e754de>       622.642        1822                0           -          5535   50                       (daemon)
         notifyd <1454674148363528952383ed99eaee44>        86.372         369                0           -           424   50                       (daemon)
     ReportCrash <e365c04793583967bc173ce46616ab70>         0.120         131                0           -           532   50                       (daemon)

**End**
```

I don't know why it crash. I even have no idea whether it is symbolized.

I will be grateful for your generous help, thanks!

Comment: This is not very readable. Did you enable exception breakpoint?

Comment: I have install it on my phone and it crashed. Then I connected it to mba to see the log.@bpolat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a crash report but LowMemory report. There's nothing to symbolicate in it, just the list of processes with how much memory / resources each was using and which ones were killed. There should be a line with your app name on it and the resources it was using. You should check that e.g. the memory in use is consistent with what you expect.

In your case, it seems that `kbd` got killed, not your app, so if your app crashed I think you are looking at the wrong file.

Comment: I enabled the zombie objects and I haven't notice the memory for a while. It seems that Process and Type in LowMemory report are Unknow?@Thomas Deniau

Comment: Zombie objects are used to track over-releases (memory you've released that you shouldn't have). Here you want to check for leaks (over-retains), which is exactly the opposite. Could you please attach the entire LowMemory report?

Comment: I have changed. Sorry for so long. I have to indent four space every line and I'm not familiar with it...

Comment: I readjusted it again. Please refresh again. Sorry for the mess.

Comment: I do not think your app was killed in this case. The report says kbd (the keyboard daemon) got killed, not your app.

Comment: Is it possible because of the third-party keyboard?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe. Anyway, this is not something you have to worry about unless you have other evidence that your app did crash.

Comment: Should I use zombie objects to track over-releases and instruments for over-retains? I'm not clear about how to use these tools.

Comment: Use the Leaks tool to track leaks and the Zombies tool to track over-releases. http://www.raywenderlich.com/23037/how-to-use-instruments-in-xcode for example

Comment: I'm so appreciate! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Steps to analyze crash report from apple:

Copy the release .app file which was pushed to the appstore, the .dSYM file that was created at the time of release and the crash report receive from APPLE into a FOLDER.

OPEN terminal application and go to the folder created above (using cd command)

Run atos -arch armv7 -o APPNAME.app/APPNAME MEMORY_LOCATION_OF_CRASH. The memory location should be the one at which the app crashed as per the report.

Ex:  atos -arch armv7  -o 'APPNAME.app'/'APPNAME' 0x0003b508

This would show you the exact line, method name which resulted in crash.

Ex: [classname functionName:]; -510

Symbolicating IPA

if we use IPA for symbolicating - just rename the extention .ipa with .zip , extract it then we can get a Payload Folder which contain app. In this case we don't need .dSYM file.

Note

This can only work if the app binary does not have symbols stripped. By default release builds stripped the symbols. We can change it in project build settings "Strip Debug Symbols During Copy" to NO.