# Swift - Making sense of iOS Crash Log

Tags: ios, swift, logging, crash

I'd had a report from a user that my app opens up, gets to the launch screen, and then crashes. He's from portugal on a iPhone 5 running iOS8. Here's his crash log - http://justpaste.it/j36w

This is my first iOS app so I'm having trouble understanding this. I see the exception that caused the crash - EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP), but I don't really understand how.

My first thought was it had something to do with localizing the strings, but he said his phone was in english. Any ideas?

Edit: http://justpaste.it/j3jy

Edit2:

```
func createBarArray(townName: String, dict: NSDictionary) -> NSMutableArray{

    var barArray = dict[townName] as NSArray
    var bars = [] as NSMutableArray

    // Get day of the week
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
    let dayOfWeekString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())

    for bar in barArray{
        var name = bar["name"] as NSString
        var dealsArr = bar[dayOfWeekString] as NSArray
        var deal = dealsArr[0] as NSString
        var lat = bar["lat"] as Double
        var long = bar["long"] as Double
        var negLong = -long

        var newBar = BarAnnotation(latitude: lat, longitude: negLong, name: name, deal: deal)

        switch(townName){
            case "amesBars":
                newBar.town = "Ames"
            case "cedarFallsBars":
                newBar.town = "Cedar Falls"
            case "iowaCityBars":
                newBar.town = "Iowa City"
            default:
                newBar.town = ""
        }

        bars.addObject(newBar)
    }

    return bars
}
```

Comment: The first thing you should try is [to symbolicate the crash log](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855389/how-to-symbolicate-crash-log-xcode-6) . Once this is done, the exact place and reason of the error should be more obvious. If not, please post here your symbolicated crash log

Comment: Well, it crahses in tabsaver with a SIGTRAP which usually indicates a wrong memory access.

Comment: I added the symbolication.

Comment: It's crashing in the createBarArray method, what is this?

Comment: Added to main post. It takes a JSON dictionary it creates an array of my custom annotation objects for the map.

Comment: I believe JSON answers are always optional. Maybe unwrapping the fields?

Answer (score 0):

Steps -

1. Get .app file
2. Get .dSYM file
3. Get the address from the crash report
4. Run `xcrun atos -o MYAPP.app/MYAPP -arch arm64 -l 0x1000f4000 0x00000001002162c8`

For better understanding check [this article](https://medium.com/@nikhilmshchs/symbolicating-ios-crash-reports-e97ad0d6b4dc#.ytz6bkr4q) out.