# Can't desymbolicate flurry crash log

Tags: ios, xcode, crash-reports, flurry

Flurry has given me a crash log from a user, but I can't desymbolicate it. Downloading the file, adding `.crash` as its extension, and then clicking "View Device Logs" in the devices tab of XCode, and dragging into the list, didn't work. It didn't allow me to drag it in. So I changed some of the header details, as somebody suggested, and it added the crashlog this time, but didn't desymbolicate it.

I need to fix this crash and this is the only thing I have pointing me to the cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just to clarify, you don't desymbolicate crash logs, you symbolicate them. Symbolication is the process of adding class symbols to crash pointers.

If you want to symbolicate your crash logs you can follow the instructions provided by ["Sea Coast of Tibet" here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855389/how-to-symbolicate-crash-log-xcode-6).

Having said that, I suggest you revisit your Flurry setup. If correctly setup all crash logs should be symbolicated on the Flurry portal.