# Can not Identify the crash Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) . Crash log included

Tags: ios, ipad, crash, ios8.3

I can not identify the problem from this crash log. I have seen several post about EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) and **CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER** but those didn't help either.This happens in OS Version:iOS 8.3 (12F69) and in iPad2.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x182b482d8 __exceptionPreprocess + 132
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1941080e4 objc_exception_throw + 60
2   CoreFoundation                  0x182a31428 -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:] + 972
3   ViadeskKit                      0x10011c5dc 0x100114000 + 34268
4   ViadeskKit                      0x10011cd98 0x100114000 + 36248
5   CoreFoundation                  0x182aee2c4 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 20
6   CoreFoundation                  0x182a2b450 _CFXNotificationPost + 2060
7   Foundation                      0x18395aa80 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 72
8   ViadeskKit                      0x100125718 0x100114000 + 71448
9   ViadeskKit                      0x100132678 0x100114000 + 124536
10  CFNetwork                       0x1825c85b8 __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke + 80
11  CFNetwork                       0x1825c8548 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 208
12  CFNetwork                       0x1825c86c4 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] + 60
13  CFNetwork                       0x18249b990 ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic26_delegate_didFinishLoadingEU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 104
14  CFNetwork                       0x18256550c ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic18_withDelegateAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP16_CFURLConnectionPK33CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMaxE_block_invoke_2 + 104
15  CFNetwork                       0x182487ac8 RunloopBlockContext::_invoke_block(void const*, void*) + 76
16  CoreFoundation                  0x182a28cdc CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
17  CFNetwork                       0x182487974 RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 136
18  CFNetwork                       0x182487828 MultiplexerSource::perform() + 312
19  CFNetwork                       0x182487654 MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) + 68
20  CoreFoundation                  0x182b00240 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
21  CoreFoundation                  0x182aff59c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 448
22  CoreFoundation                  0x182afd594 __CFRunLoopRun + 712
23  CoreFoundation                  0x182a292d4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
24  GraphicsServices                0x18c1076fc GSEventRunModal + 168
25  UIKit                           0x1875eefac UIApplicationMain + 1488
26  Viadesk                         0x10004e4d8 main (main.m:16)
27  libdyld.dylib                   0x194786a08 start + 4


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019489f270 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019493d16c pthread_kill + 108
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000194816b14 abort + 108
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001938d5414 abort_message + 112
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001938f4b88 default_terminate_handler() + 300
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001941083bc _objc_terminate() + 124
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001938f1bb0 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 12
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001938f1474 __cxa_throw + 132
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000194108200 objc_exception_throw + 344
9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182a31424 -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:] + 968
10  ViadeskKit                      0x000000010011c5d8 0x100114000 + 34264
11  ViadeskKit                      0x000000010011cd94 0x100114000 + 36244
12  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182aee2c0 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 16
13  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182a2b44c _CFXNotificationPost + 2056
14  Foundation                      0x000000018395aa7c -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 68
15  ViadeskKit                      0x0000000100125714 0x100114000 + 71444
16  ViadeskKit                      0x0000000100132674 0x100114000 + 124532
17  CFNetwork                       0x00000001825c85b4 __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke + 76
18  CFNetwork                       0x00000001825c8544 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 204
19  CFNetwork                       0x00000001825c86c0 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] + 56
20  CFNetwork                       0x000000018249b98c ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic26_delegate_didFinishLoadingEU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 100
21  CFNetwork                       0x0000000182565508 ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic18_withDelegateAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP16_CFURLConnectionPK33CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMaxE_block_invoke_2 + 100
22  CFNetwork                       0x0000000182487ac4 RunloopBlockContext::_invoke_block(void const*, void*) + 72
23  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182a28cd8 CFArrayApplyFunction + 64
24  CFNetwork                       0x0000000182487970 RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 132
25  CFNetwork                       0x0000000182487824 MultiplexerSource::perform() + 308
26  CFNetwork                       0x0000000182487650 MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) + 64
27  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182b0023c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 20
28  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182aff598 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 444
29  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182afd590 __CFRunLoopRun + 708
30  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182a292d0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
31  GraphicsServices                0x000000018c1076f8 GSEventRunModal + 164
32  UIKit                           0x00000001875eefa8 UIApplicationMain + 1484
33  Viadesk                         0x000000010004e4d4 main (main.m:16)
34  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000194786a04 start + 0
```

Comment: Add more information surrounding the crash, breakpoint your code and show us where it crashes.

Comment: @Schemetrical, I received this from users devices. When I run the project in Xcode  it doesn't crash at all. This is the confusing part. I have only this crash log to identify the bug.

Comment: Looks like setting a nil object as a value in a dictionary (right after NSNotification is posted).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stacktrace needs to be symbolicated so you can see what `0x10011c5dc 0x100114000 + 34268` actually means (i.e. what source file and line).  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855389/how-to-symbolicate-crash-log-xcode-6) for details.

The crash occurs in `[NSMutableDictionary setObject:forKey:]` and one very common reason for a crash in that method is that the object is `nil` and you cannot hold `nil` in Objective-C collection classes.  However there should have been some *exception text* generated which can confirm this.

That's about all I can tell you at this stage.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am trying to symbolicate. I also guessed at some point of my application it is trying to set object for nil key. I have to find out that point. But the crash log do not point to a class name from where is it is occurring.

Comment: @eNipu It will once you've successfully symbolicated the crash log.  That success will depend if you have the `.dsym` for the app.

Comment: Finally I found the bug. I was creating UIImage from NSData and set them in NSDictionary. I have not checked nil image exception. It was hard to find the bug from crash log as it has not indication of the class from here it was originating.