# iOS8 crashed with __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__

Tags: ios

```
#0
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x00000001625fbeb8
0
libobjc.A.dylib 
objc_msgSend + 16
1   CoreFoundation  
__CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 20
2   CoreFoundation  
_CFXNotificationPost + 2060
3
Foundation  
-[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 72
```

The bug occurred infrequently.So It's too hard for me to find out why.
From the infomation I know It's occurred after a postNotification,but I found all the places where receive the notification and i write this in dealloc "[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self]".
Does anyone know any other possibility?

Comment: try removing the observers in viewwilldisappear rather than dealloc.

Comment: see this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30420420/can-not-identify-the-crash-exception-type-exc-crash-sigabrt-crash-log-inclu