# Xcode 6.3.2 App crashes after loading launch screen

Tags: ios, xcode, crash

My app will run on xcode's simulators without crashing, and on my ios device (through xcode) without crashing as well.

However, when I export the build as an ipa file and add it to my device through itunes, it launches and then crashes after the launch screen appears for it's assigned time. This is for ad hoc and app store ipa files. Apple rejected my app for this reason.

Do you know why this crash is happening?

Thanks!

Here is the crash log:

https://www.scribd.com/doc/269784196/Xcode-6-3-2-launching-crash

Comment: Please post the full crashlog/backtrace.  It is impossible to know what is going on without more context.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my post and added links to the crashlogs.

Comment: Your logs have not been desymbolicated.  How are we supposed to figure out where your crash is when every line in your backtrace looks like `0x000000010002288c 0x100008000 + 108684`?

Comment: How do I desymbolicate the logs? This is what apple gave me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855389/how-to-symbolicate-crash-log-xcode-6

Comment: I uploaded the logs from my device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your target 'copy bundle resources' section.

From your log, it seems like some nib can not be loaded. (possible source of error - your SWRevealViewController. check, if everything was copied correctly and re-add it if needed. I recommend you reinstall this library.

Comment: I checked the copy bundle section, and re-added the SWRevealViewController files. Do I need to link the binary with a library for the SWRevealViewController files?

Comment: if you add library manually, make sure all files was copied (you can select 'copy items if needed'). If you are using pods, it's unnecessary