# Apple rejected my app though it works on my iPhone and on the simulator

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, crash-log

I have sent my app to apple so they can review it. My app works fine on the simulator and on my iPhone 5 but Apple rejected my app because they say it crashes and they have attached a crash log but I can't find the error.

```
 Incident Identifier: AD44C53C-F5D1-41CF-ADF4-4647804D553B
CrashReporter Key:   f3b2028de832a8615d68a6966f72b02d8a6247ca
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             Bouncy Blop [215]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/FD073868-42C5-4423-A21B-2C8291B04B7A/Bouncy Blop.app/Bouncy Blop
Identifier:          MPritz.com.example.Bouncy-Blop
Version:             4 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-07-28 17:12:34.017 -0700
Launch Time:         2015-07-28 17:12:33.602 -0700
OS Version:          iOS 8.4 (12H143)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x1845082d8 0x1960d80e4 0x184508218 0x188e1d210 0x188dc2440 0x1000405e8 0x10003cbcc 0x188ddb770 0x188df3004 0x10004de50 0x10004c6f4 0x188f80c18 0x188f80928 0x188f87164 0x188f84814 0x188ff6880 0x18920aa28 0x18920d19c 0x18920b70c 0x18cc153c8 0x1844c027c 0x1844bf384 0x1844bd9a8 0x1843e92d4 0x188fec3d0 0x188fe6f40 0x100050e3c 0x196782a08)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019689b270 0x196880000 + 111216
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019693916c 0x196934000 + 20844
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000196812b14 0x1967b0000 + 404244
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001958a5414 0x1958a4000 + 5140
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001958c4b88 0x1958a4000 + 134024
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001960d83bc 0x1960d0000 + 33724
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001958c1bb0 0x1958a4000 + 121776
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001958c1738 0x1958a4000 + 120632
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001960d8290 0x1960d0000 + 33424
9   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001843e9380 0x1843e0000 + 37760
10  UIKit                           0x0000000188fec3cc 0x188f70000 + 508876
11  UIKit                           0x0000000188fe6f3c 0x188f70000 + 487228
12  Bouncy Blop                     0x0000000100050e38 0x100034000 + 118328
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000196782a04 0x196780000 + 10756

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196880c24 0x196880000 + 3108
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000196765e6c 0x196754000 + 73324
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000196757998 0x196754000 + 14744

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019689bc78 0x196880000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001969352d8 0x196934000 + 4824
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000196934eec 0x196934000 + 3820

Thread 3 name:  Dispatch queue: FBSSerialQueue
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196880e48 0x196880000 + 3656
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000196763f3c 0x196754000 + 65340
2   FrontBoardServices              0x000000018cc15384 0x18cbfc000 + 103300
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000196755990 0x196754000 + 6544
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000196755950 0x196754000 + 6480
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001967600a0 0x196754000 + 49312
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000196758a58 0x196754000 + 19032
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000196762314 0x196754000 + 58132
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000196763c48 0x196754000 + 64584
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000196935228 0x196934000 + 4648
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000196934eec 0x196934000 + 3820

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019689bc78 0x196880000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001969352d8 0x196934000 + 4824
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000196934eec 0x196934000 + 3820

Thread 5 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.gamecenter.GKDaemonProxy
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196880e48 0x196880000 + 3656
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000196764288 0x196754000 + 66184
2   GameCenterFoundation            0x000000018d62dfe0 0x18d5dc000 + 335840
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000196755990 0x196754000 + 6544
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000196755950 0x196754000 + 6480
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001967600a0 0x196754000 + 49312
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000196758a58 0x196754000 + 19032
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000196762314 0x196754000 + 58132
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000196763c48 0x196754000 + 64584
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000196935228 0x196934000 + 4648
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000196934eec 0x196934000 + 3820

Thread 6 name:  WebThread
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019689b0c0 0x196880000 + 110784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000196935490 0x196934000 + 5264
2   WebCore                         0x0000000192f660c0 0x192eb4000 + 729280
3   WebCore                         0x0000000192f66024 0x192eb4000 + 729124
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001844c02a0 0x1843e0000 + 918176
5   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001844bd22c 0x1843e0000 + 905772
6   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001844bd700 0x1843e0000 + 907008
7   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001843e92d0 0x1843e0000 + 37584
8   WebCore                         0x0000000192f642e0 0x192eb4000 + 721632
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000196937dc4 0x196934000 + 15812
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000196937d20 0x196934000 + 15648
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000196934ef4 0x196934000 + 3828

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019689bc78 0x196880000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001969352d8 0x196934000 + 4824
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000196934eec 0x196934000 + 3820

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019689bc78 0x196880000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001969352d8 0x196934000 + 4824
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000196934eec 0x196934000 + 3820

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019689bc78 0x196880000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001969352d8 0x196934000 + 4824
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000196934eec 0x196934000 + 3820

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x00000001740e3d37
    x4: 0x00000001958c5dfd   x5: 0x000000016fdcb410   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000fa0
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x0000000000000200  x11: 0x0000000000000000
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x0000000000000002  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x000000019a865310  x21: 0x000000019a84dce8  x22: 0x000000017014f2c0  x23: 0x0000000196da8f50
   x24: 0x0000000000000001  x25: 0x000000017014f2b0  x26: 0x000000019a84c0a8  x27: 0x0000000000000001
   x28: 0x0000000000000000  fp: 0x000000016fdcb370   lr: 0x0000000196939170
    sp: 0x000000016fdcb350   pc: 0x000000019689b270 cpsr: 0x00000000
```

Comment: You need to [symbolicate your crash logs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25855389/1445366).

Comment: Try to import crash log into Xcode to have symbols instead of addresses and offsets.

Comment: And how can I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855389/how-to-symbolicate-crash-log-xcode-6

Comment: You can also send a "preview" of what apple will see about your app with testflight so you can see if the app is actually crashing.

Comment: Ok I have symbolicated the crash log and now?

Comment: @MichaelPritz could you update your current crash with symbolicated one?

Comment: I've symbolicated my crash log and now I know that the reason for the crash were missing sound files. Thank you