# How to symbolicate crash log with Xcode 7?

Tags: xcode7, symbolicatecrash

So the technique I was using with Xcode 6 appears to be deprecated, the symbolicatecrash.sh script is not located in the xcode bundle anymore.  Instead there is an executable named symbolicatecrash in the same folder path as Xcode 6 had the script.

Anyone know where Apple moved symbolicatecrash.sh for manual symbolication?   The script from Xcode 6 gives errors running with Xcode 7.

Comment: @null organizer does not symbolicate for me, so it's not a sure fire thing for everyone

Comment: @jjxtra there are ways to solve that, specifically you need to make sure your build settings are correctly configured (see here: http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-ios-mac-os-x/how-to-solve-symbolication-problems#build-settings-for-getting-proper-symbol-data). It's worth taking the time getting xcode to work properly since using the Organizer is soooo much easier than manual symbolication.

Comment: @null I did eventually get it symbolicated doing it manually. I'll look at hockey app.

Comment: If you're using PLCrashReporter as I am you are getting reports that never come thru Apple into Xcode organizer.    I rarely if ever see an Organizer crash reported.  Command line symbolication works just fine with the accepted answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have Xcode 7 installed and `symbolicatecrash` in `/usr/bin` is a symbolic link to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DTDeviceKitBase.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash`.

I have no problem manually symbolicating crash reports with Xcode 7 just as I have for the last several releases of Xcode.

BTW - it's still a `perl` script as always.

And be sure you have installed the Xcode command line tools.

*Update*

With Xcode 7.3 the location of `symbolicatecrash` is `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash`.

I've also seen that since upgrading to OS X 10.11 (El Capitan), there is no longer a symbolic link in `/usr/bin`.

Comment: Thanks, its been so long that I needed to manually symbolicate a PLCrashReporter file I forgot where I had this sh wrapper from!  Still getting an odd error to figure out where symbolicatecrash emits "xcodebuild: error: SDK 'ipados' cannot be located" and then chokes up.

Comment: @rmaddy could you please show what that line in terminal looks like? I have the .dYSM files and crash file, but can't figure out the terminal command. Thanks!

Comment: @drshock did you ever find a solution to your "xcodebuild: error: SDK 'ipados' cannot be located"?

Comment: @canton7 the script pulls this from the Hardware model line of the crash log.  I was pressed for time and just changed it to iPhone instead of iPad.  Didn't look into why it got confused.

Comment: in Xcode7.3, it's in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash`