# Discovering the issue in Xcode crash report

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, crash

I am having trouble trying to understand what went wrong when my app crashed for a user based on a crash report i received back.

In Xcode organizer I can see the following:
[image: Xcode Organiser Crash Report Screen Shot]

I can open the crash report in project but all I get is:
[image: Screen Shot of Crash Report Open in Xcode]

This part doesn't change if I select any individual thread, I can't see any variables and it doesn't even tell me what line of code the thread was suspended at. Does anyone have any suggestions of how I should continue to debug this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your log say?

Comment: Elaborate how and why crash occur in your project

Comment: SO the crash occurred by some public user of the app and Xcode has reported it back to me through the organiser window, I can not symbolicate it as has been suggested, looks like a similar issue to this person http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33131434/new-xcode-crash-organizer-does-not-symbolicate-xccrashpoint-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all this crash report is not symbolicated. You should do that. Xcode would do that for you if you download the crash report by Organizer.

Second, this exception usually occurs if you the index specified in objectAtIndex is too large. So if you don't have access to symbolication for this crash report then all you could do is to check all your objectAtIndex: calls to see if the index could get outside of the bounds.

Comment: I am unable to symbolicate the crash, looks similar to this guy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33131434/new-xcode-crash-organizer-does-not-symbolicate-xccrashpoint-files

Comment: Was it a bit code build? If not, then you need to get the dsym from your the machine where you did Build&Archive and manually symbolicate it.