# How to run symbolicatecrash tool in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, crash-reports, symbolicatecrash

This has been driving me nuts for two days. I have an app live in the App Store and have downloaded my crash reports to Xcode Organizer, but they aren't symbolicated (thanks Apple). I've tried various fixes to symbolicate them from reading other threads and forums, but no luck.

My last resort seems to be manual symbolication using the symbolicatecrash tool, but I am a total noob with command line and need some help.

I have my original build which I uploaded to the App Store, and from that I have retrieved **MyAppName.app.dSYM** and **MyAppName.app** files. I have also located the **.crash** reports

From what I've read, that should be enough to symbolicate the crash reports. So could someone please walk me through the steps required to get this working? I've got as far as placing the **.dSYM**, **.app** and **.crash** files in a directory and opening up Terminal - now I'm stuck (feel free to talk to me like I'm a 7 year old!)

**Edit:**

After managing to run symbolicatecrash, I get the following output which seems to signify an error (note I replaced my app name with **MyApp** and obviously this is only some of the output from the console, ie the part with the error messages):

```
.....fetching symbol file for MyApp--[undef] 
Searching []...-- NO MATCH
Searching in Spotlight for dsym with UUID of 2b804cc860e136529ae12ed16bc274e7
Running mdfind "com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids ==     2B804CC8-60E1-3652-9AE1-2ED16BC274E7"
Running mdls -name com_apple_xcode_dsym_paths \/Users\/Steve\/Library \/Developer\/Xcode\/Archives\/2015\-11\-04\/MyApp\ 04\-11\-2015\,\ 19\.01 \.xcarchive
@dsym_paths = ( /Users/Steve/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2015-11-04    /MyApp 04-11-2015, 19.01.xcarchive/dSYMs /2b804cc8-60e1-3652-9ae1-2ed16bc274e7.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/MyApp /Users/Steve/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2015-11-04/MyApp 04-11-2015, 19.01.xcarchive/dSYMs/7abb6a6c-91be-3da0-af0f-2cc21f9a6b83.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/MyApp /Users/Steve/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2015-11-04/MyApp 04-11-2015, 19.01.xcarchive/dSYMs/MyApp.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/MyApp )
@exec_names = ( MyApp )
Running mdfind "kMDItemContentType == com.apple.application-bundle && (kMDItemAlternateNames == 'MyApp.app' || kMDItemDisplayName == 'MyApp' || kMDItemDisplayName == 'MyApp.app')"
Running mdfind "kMDItemContentType == public.unix-executable && kMDItemDisplayName == 'MyApp'"
Running find "/Users/Steve/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2015-11-04/MyApp 04-11-2015, 19.01.xcarchive/Products" -name "MyApp.app"
Running /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo -info '/Users/Steve/Desktop/MyApp/MyApp.app/MyApp'
Running /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/otool -arch arm64 -l '/Users/Steve/Desktop/MyApp/MyApp.app/MyApp'
Given UUID 2b804cc860e136529ae12ed16bc274e7 for '/Users/Steve/Desktop/MyApp/MyApp.app/MyApp' is really UUID 1a2c967bf1c3357aa24b1a28337ff8dd
UUID of executable is: 2b804cc860e136529ae12ed16bc274e7
Executable name: /Users/Steve/Desktop/MyApp/MyApp.app/MyApp

UUID doesn't match dsym for executable /Users/Steve/Desktop/MyApp/MyApp.app/MyApp
Running /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo -info '/Users/Steve/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dlbyzstivqblnbfcbzdceqzdpyje/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/MyApp'
Running /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/otool -arch arm64 -l '/Users/Steve/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dlbyzstivqblnbfcbzdceqzdpyje/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/MyApp'
Given UUID 2b804cc860e136529ae12ed16bc274e7 for '/Users/Steve/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dlbyzstivqblnbfcbzdceqzdpyje/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/MyApp' is really UUID 9c98651607a83822b051b57a71c62e29
UUID of executable is: 2b804cc860e136529ae12ed16bc274e7
Executable name: /Users/Steve/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dlbyzstivqblnbfcbzdceqzdpyje/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/MyApp

UUID doesn't match dsym for executable /Users/Steve/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dlbyzstivqblnbfcbzdceqzdpyje/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/MyApp
Running /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo -info '/Users/Steve/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dlbyzstivqblnbfcbzdceqzdpyje/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/MyApp'
## /Users/Steve/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dlbyzstivqblnbfcbzdceqzdpyje/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app    /MyApp doesn't contain arm64 slice
UUID of executable is: 2b804cc860e136529ae12ed16bc274e7
Executable name: /Users/Steve/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dlbyzstivqblnbfcbzdceqzdpyje/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/MyApp

UUID doesn't match dsym for executable /Users/Steve/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dlbyzstivqblnbfcbzdceqzdpyje/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/MyApp
Running /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo -info '/Users/Steve/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2015-11-04/MyApp 04-11-2015, 19.01.xcarchive/Products/Applications/MyApp.app/MyApp'
Running /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/otool -arch arm64 -l '/Users/Steve/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2015-11-04/MyApp 04-11-2015, 19.01.xcarchive/Products/Applications/MyApp.app/MyApp'
Given UUID 2b804cc860e136529ae12ed16bc274e7 for '/Users/Steve/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2015-11-04/MyApp 04-11-2015, 19.01.xcarchive/Products/Applications/MyApp.app/MyApp' is really UUID 1a2c967bf1c3357aa24b1a28337ff8dd
UUID of executable is: 2b804cc860e136529ae12ed16bc274e7
Executable name: /Users/Steve/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2015-11-04/MyApp 04-11-2015, 19.01.xcarchive/Products/Applications/MyApp.app/MyApp

UUID doesn't match dsym for executable /Users/Steve/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2015-11-04/MyApp 04-11-2015, 19.01.xcarchive/Products/Applications/MyApp.app/MyApp
Did not find executable for dsym
## Warning: Can't find any unstripped binary that matches version of /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/8C991754-A7C3-4B4F-B88E-6F0A87881CD4/MyApp.app/MyApp
```

What does this mean?

Comment: I had same issue , i am able to symbolicate using  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30431450/1597744) .  Have you triedit?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32804611/how-to-symbolicate-crash-log-with-xcode-7

Comment: @Viruss mca Thank you, that link was helpful (not sure how I missed it!) and I have now been able to run symbolicatecrash. But it didn't symbolicate the report - instead I got some error messages that I've edited into my question above.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up trying to make this work and instead uploaded my crash report to Hockey App: http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-ios-mac-os-x/how-to-manually-upload-and-symbolicate-a-crash

It was painless and the whole process of joining Hockey App, uploading my build, dSYM file and crash report took 10 minutes. Almost immediately I was reading a symbolicated report with a stacktrace that made sense.

In the future I will use Hockey App in my apps for crash reporting.

Why can't you be like this Apple?!