# Unable to symbolicate crash log on Xcode 7.2

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, symbolicatecrash, symbolicate

I've crash log, .dsym, .app but am unable to symbolicate crash log. It returns error 
'xcodebuild: error: SDK "ipados" cannot be located.'

Comment: see this link it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32804611/how-to-symbolicate-crash-log-with-xcode-7