# Crash reports aren't symbolicated in XCode often

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, app-store-connect

**Background:**

I am using a Continuous Integration service which builds and pushes apps to iTunes connect. As result, I am not pushing them through XCode (which is probably common way of doing this)

**Problem**

The app crashed on the device and crash logs got uploaded to iTunes/iTunes connect and my XCode downloaded it (I can see it in Organizer crashes).

I looked in the Organizer and was puzzled:

- All crash report for one build are symbolicated
- All crash reports for another build aren't symbolicated

I need to somehow to symbolicate a crash or at least figure out how to make all future crashes symbolicated.

**Attempts so solve**

I thought to symbolicate them manually ([How to symbolicate crash log Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855389/how-to-symbolicate-crash-log-xcode)) However, you need (apparently) .app which I can't download from iTunes connect (.dSYM are available, but not .app).

Three related questions:

- Do you know why half of them are symbolicated and another half is not?
- Have you seen instabilities in symbolication? (if it's widespread, I probably need to switch to Crashalytics or something like that).
- Who is symbolicating crashes (XCode or iTunes connect)?