# Where is located symbolicatecrash in Xcode 8?

Tags: xcode, xcode8, symbolicatecrash

Where is located **symbolicatecrash** tool in Xcode 8?

In Xcode 7 it used to be here:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DTDeviceKitBase.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found it at...

```
./Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash
```

...in the Xcode.app folder.

For reference, "`find . -name symbolicatecrash`" in the terminal is your friend.

Comment: Found it here  /Applications/Xcode 8.2.1.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash