# Decifrate User Crash Log File iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, ios10, logfile

A user of mine app send me a crash log file, because when he press a button the app crash. In my devices I don't have any crashes. 
Can you help me with the log file? I don't understand what's part of my code is wrong

Thank you

Here is the log :

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x18cf3efd8 0x18b9a0538 0x18ce21d1c 0x10017bea4 0x198ce3a10 0x198cd0e74 0x198cda7c8 0x198cde874 0x198cde6c4 0x198ce3374 0x10017b838 0x10017c1f8 0x193085cd0 0x193085a40 0x19320a2a0 0x193124c4c 0x1931248b4 0x193124818 0x19306b158 0x19025b274 0x19024fde8 0x19024fca8 0x1901cb360 0x1901f23c0 0x1901f2e8c 0x18ceec9a0 0x18ceea628 0x18ceeaa74 0x18ce1ad94 0x18e884074 0x1930d3130 0x100198490 0x18be2959c)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018bf39014 0x18bf1a000 + 126996
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018c003334 0x18bffe000 + 21300
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018bead9c4 0x18be4c000 + 399812
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018b9791b0 0x18b978000 + 4528
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018b992c04 0x18b978000 + 109572
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018b9a0820 0x18b998000 + 34848
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018b98f5d4 0x18b978000 + 95700
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018b98f1a8 0x18b978000 + 94632
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018b9a06f8 0x18b998000 + 34552
9   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ce1ae00 0x18ce12000 + 36352
10  GraphicsServices                0x000000018e884074 0x18e878000 + 49268
11  UIKit                           0x00000001930d3130 0x19305e000 + 479536
12  Reflex                          0x0000000100198490 0x1000b4000 + 935056
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018be2959c 0x18be25000 + 17820

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018bffed78 0x18bffe000 + 3448

Thread 2 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018bf1b224 0x18bf1a000 + 4644
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018bf1b09c 0x18bf1a000 + 4252
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ceece88 0x18ce12000 + 896648
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ceeaadc 0x18ce12000 + 887516
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ce1ad94 0x18ce12000 + 36244
5   Foundation                      0x000000018d934d64 0x18d928000 + 52580
6   Foundation                      0x000000018d955b34 0x18d928000 + 187188
7   UIKit                           0x0000000193a5d5f8 0x19305e000 + 10483192
8   Foundation                      0x000000018da322c8 0x18d928000 + 1090248
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018c00175c 0x18bffe000 + 14172
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018c00166c 0x18bffe000 + 13932
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018bffed84 0x18bffe000 + 3460

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018bf1b224 0x18bf1a000 + 4644
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018bf1b09c 0x18bf1a000 + 4252
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ceece88 0x18ce12000 + 896648
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ceeaadc 0x18ce12000 + 887516
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ce1ad94 0x18ce12000 + 36244
5   CFNetwork                       0x000000018d626ca4 0x18d545000 + 924836
6   Foundation                      0x000000018da322c8 0x18d928000 + 1090248
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018c00175c 0x18bffe000 + 14172
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018c00166c 0x18bffe000 + 13932
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018bffed84 0x18bffe000 + 3460

Thread 4 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.CoreLocation.ConnectionClient.0x170136da0.events
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018bf1b278 0x18bf1a000 + 4728
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018be096b4 0x18bdf5000 + 83636
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018be08c5c 0x18bdf5000 + 80988
3   CoreLocation                    0x00000001951af180 0x1951ac000 + 12672
4   CoreLocation                    0x00000001951b4220 0x1951ac000 + 33312
5   CoreLocation                    0x00000001951b4020 0x1951ac000 + 32800
6   CoreLocation                    0x00000001951ffee8 0x1951ac000 + 343784
7   CoreLocation                    0x00000001951fc550 0x1951ac000 + 329040
8   CoreLocation                    0x00000001951fc474 0x1951ac000 + 328820
9   CoreLocation                    0x00000001951fdae0 0x1951ac000 + 334560
10  libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018c033854 0x18c02e000 + 22612
11  libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018c031360 0x18c02e000 + 13152
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018bdf6a70 0x18bdf5000 + 6768
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018bdfa5f0 0x18bdf5000 + 22000
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018be04964 0x18bdf5000 + 63844
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018bdf9a2c 0x18bdf5000 + 18988
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018be04964 0x18bdf5000 + 63844
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018bdfa2cc 0x18bdf5000 + 21196
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018be04964 0x18bdf5000 + 63844
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018bdfa2cc 0x18bdf5000 + 21196
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018be05950 0x18bdf5000 + 67920
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018be0c170 0x18bdf5000 + 94576
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018bfff08c 0x18bffe000 + 4236
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018bffed7c 0x18bffe000 + 3452

Thread 5 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.CoreLocation.ConnectionClient.0x170134500.events
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018bf1b278 0x18bf1a000 + 4728
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018be096b4 0x18bdf5000 + 83636
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018be08c5c 0x18bdf5000 + 80988
3   CoreLocation                    0x00000001951af180 0x1951ac000 + 12672
4   CoreLocation                    0x00000001951b4220 0x1951ac000 + 33312
5   CoreLocation                    0x00000001951b4020 0x1951ac000 + 32800
6   CoreLocation                    0x00000001951ffee8 0x1951ac000 + 343784
7   CoreLocation                    0x00000001951fc550 0x1951ac000 + 329040
8   CoreLocation                    0x00000001951fc474 0x1951ac000 + 328820
9   CoreLocation                    0x00000001951fdae0 0x1951ac000 + 334560
10  libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018c033854 0x18c02e000 + 22612
11  libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018c031360 0x18c02e000 + 13152
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018bdf6a70 0x18bdf5000 + 6768
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018bdfa5f0 0x18bdf5000 + 22000
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018be04964 0x18bdf5000 + 63844
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018bdf9a2c 0x18bdf5000 + 18988
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018be04964 0x18bdf5000 + 63844
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018bdfa2cc 0x18bdf5000 + 21196
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018be04964 0x18bdf5000 + 63844
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018bdfa2cc 0x18bdf5000 + 21196
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018be05950 0x18bdf5000 + 67920
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018be0c170 0x18bdf5000 + 94576
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018bfff08c 0x18bffe000 + 4236
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018bffed7c 0x18bffe000 + 3452

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018bf39a88 0x18bf1a000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018bfff274 0x18bffe000 + 4724
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018bffed7c 0x18bffe000 + 3452

Thread 7 name:  AVAudioSession Notify Thread
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018bf1b224 0x18bf1a000 + 4644
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018bf1b09c 0x18bf1a000 + 4252
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ceece88 0x18ce12000 + 896648
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ceeaadc 0x18ce12000 + 887516
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ce1ad94 0x18ce12000 + 36244
5   AVFAudio                        0x00000001a7154540 0x1a70e0000 + 476480
6   AVFAudio                        0x00000001a717a814 0x1a70e0000 + 632852
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018c00175c 0x18bffe000 + 14172
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018c00166c 0x18bffe000 + 13932
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018bffed84 0x18bffe000 + 3460

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018bf39a88 0x18bf1a000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018bfff0a0 0x18bffe000 + 4256
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018bffed7c 0x18bffe000 + 3452

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018bf39a88 0x18bf1a000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018bfff274 0x18bffe000 + 4724
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018bffed7c 0x18bffe000 + 3452

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018bf1b278 0x18bf1a000 + 4728
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018be096b4 0x18bdf5000 + 83636
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018be08c5c 0x18bdf5000 + 80988
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018be07f48 0x18bdf5000 + 77640
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018c00175c 0x18bffe000 + 14172
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018c00166c 0x18bffe000 + 13932
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018bffed84 0x18bffe000 + 3460

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x00000001744f7337
    x4: 0x000000018b993b07   x5: 0x000000016fd4b580   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0xffffffffffffffec
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x000000000000000b  x11: 0x000000000000000b
   x12: 0x0000000000000010  x13: 0x000000018d189c0e  x14: 0x0000030000000300  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x00000001b31f0b40  x21: 0x000000016fd4b580  x22: 0x00000001b31f7bb8  x23: 0x0000000000000001
   x24: 0x0000000170004670  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x0000000000000001  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x000000016fd4bbe0   fp: 0x000000016fd4b4e0   lr: 0x000000018c003334
    sp: 0x000000016fd4b4c0   pc: 0x000000018bf39014 cpsr: 0x00000000
```

**Edited Log** :

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x18cf3efd8 __exceptionPreprocess + 124
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x18b9a0538 objc_exception_throw + 56
2   CoreFoundation                  0x18ce21d1c -[__NSArrayM replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:] + 440
3   Reflex                          0x10017bea4 __48-[AAPLRootListViewController metotoAggiornaFoto]_block_invoke.141 (AAPLRootListViewController.m:221)
4   Photos                          0x198ce3a10 __84-[PHImageManager requestImageForAsset:targetSize:contentMode:options:resultHandler:]_block_invoke.1571 + 824
5   Photos                          0x198cd0e74 -[PHCoreImageManager _fetchAnySizeImageAsNon5551BytesWithRequest:library:format:bestFormat:optimalSourcePixelSize:sync:fireAndForgetCPLDownload:completionHandler:] + 4984
6   Photos                          0x198cda7c8 -[PHCoreImageManager _processImageRequest:sync:] + 6204
7   Photos                          0x198cde874 -[PHImageManager requestAsynchronousImageForAsset:chainedToMasterRequest:targetSize:contentMode:options:resultHandler:] + 380
8   Photos                          0x198cde6c4 -[PHImageManager requestAsynchronousImageForAsset:targetSize:contentMode:options:resultHandler:] + 116
9   Photos                          0x198ce3374 -[PHImageManager requestImageForAsset:targetSize:contentMode:options:resultHandler:] + 708
10  Reflex                          0x10017b838 -[AAPLRootListViewController metotoAggiornaFoto] (AAPLRootListViewController.m:215)
11  Reflex                          0x10017c1f8 -[AAPLRootListViewController viewWillAppear:] (AAPLRootListViewController.m:288)
12  UIKit                           0x193085cd0 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 632
13  UIKit                           0x193085a40 -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 156
14  UIKit                           0x19320a2a0 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 1144
15  UIKit                           0x193124c4c -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 676
16  UIKit                           0x1931248b4 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 64
17  UIKit                           0x193124818 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 188
18  UIKit                           0x19306b158 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1200
19  QuartzCore                      0x19025b274 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
20  QuartzCore                      0x19024fde8 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 292
21  QuartzCore                      0x19024fca8 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 32
22  QuartzCore                      0x1901cb360 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 252
23  QuartzCore                      0x1901f23c0 CA::Transaction::commit() + 504
24  QuartzCore                      0x1901f2e8c CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 120
25  CoreFoundation                  0x18ceec9a0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
26  CoreFoundation                  0x18ceea628 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372
27  CoreFoundation                  0x18ceeaa74 __CFRunLoopRun + 956
28  CoreFoundation                  0x18ce1ad94 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
29  GraphicsServices                0x18e884074 GSEventRunModal + 100
30  UIKit                           0x1930d3130 UIApplicationMain + 208
31  Reflex                          0x100198490 main (main.m:14)
32  libdyld.dylib                   0x18be2959c start + 4


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018bf39014 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018c003334 pthread_kill + 112
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018bead9c4 abort + 140
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018b9791b0 __cxa_bad_cast + 0
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018b992c04 default_unexpected_handler() + 0
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018b9a0820 _objc_terminate() + 124
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018b98f5d4 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018b98f1a8 __cxa_rethrow + 144
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018b9a06f8 objc_exception_rethrow + 44
9   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ce1ae00 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 532
10  GraphicsServices                0x000000018e884074 GSEventRunModal + 100
11  UIKit                           0x00000001930d3130 UIApplicationMain + 208
12  Reflex                          0x0000000100198490 main (main.m:14)
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018be2959c start + 4
```

Comment: Can you please symbolicate the log and create a [mcve]?

Comment: @NobodyNada I'm sorry, can you help me with the symbolication?

Comment: You can try some of [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855389/how-to-symbolicate-crash-log-xcode).

Comment: @NobodyNada thx, I edited the question

Comment: Thanks for symbolicating the crash log; however, the question is still missing an MCVE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) implies that the process was terminated due to an uncaught Objective-C exception.
2. Frame 1 of the crashed thread’s backtrace (objc_exception_throw) indicates that this was an unhandled language exception (NSException in this case).
3. Frame 2 indicates that it was thrown by an NSMutableArray (__NSArrayM) when someone called -replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:
4. Frame 3 indicates that that ‘someone’ was your code, namely, [AAPLRootListViewController metotoAggiornaFoto] at line 221 of AAPLRootListViewController.m.