# Unable to Symbolicate iOS App Crash Report i did all possible valid scenario. What are all possible thing A iOS app Symbolication Failed

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

i tried these thing but no luck till now.
1.Need App.carsh, App.dSYM, App.app files in one folder
2. cd folder path
3. xcrun atos -o OrderCommitV2.app/OrderCommitV2 -arch arm64 -l 
    [How to symbolicate crash log Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855389/how-to-symbolicate-crash-log-xcode)

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest way IMO, you'll need both archive and crash files

1. Open Xcode and connect any device
2. Go to Window/Organizer and load your archive there
3. Go to Window/Devices and simulator and load your crash log
4. Right click and tap Re-symbolicate log (it might take a few repetitions)

Now you can see exactly where the crash happened in your app.