# EXC_CRASH(SIGABRT) How to locate relevant information from the crash report

Tags: ios, swift, crash

I have been spending hours trying to locate the error from the crash report but without any success. This is a crash report obtained from Apple after submitting to Apple to review. I could not reproduce the error/crash when they were testing the "taking photo" feature.Can someone point me to a direction?

```
Incident Identifier: A1D97BC0-1ADC-4BBB-9E93-B715BFCAB1F9
CrashReporter Key:   76499241dcdacdbbbe8b2d13cec556a542d621f2
Hardware Model:      xxx1
Process:             xxxx [8001]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F3EE3E40-C05D-45C7-83B4-124F597DB19A/Yall.app/Yall
Identifier:          xxxxxxxx
Version:             1.0.9 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           xxxxxxxx [2900]


Date/Time:           2018-03-05 10:43:50.1248 -0800
Launch Time:         2018-03-05 10:43:47.9739 -0800
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.2.6 (15D100)
Baseband Version:    n/a
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x183a9f164 0x182ce8528 0x1894a7ca8 0x1044ef0a0 0x1044ed6ac 0x18d6f6ca4 0x18d6fb298 0x18d1d3a14 0x18d08ab50 0x18d6e4b08 0x18d6e4678 0x18d6e37d4 0x18d088e5c 0x18d059e7c 0x18d9af30c 0x18d9b1898 0x18d9aa7b0 0x183a4777c 0x183a476fc 0x183a46f84 0x183a44b5c 0x183964c58 0x185810f84 0x18d0bd5c4 0x10445944c 0x18348456c)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001835b42e8 0x183592000 + 140008
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001836c92f8 0x1836c6000 + 13048
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000183522fbc 0x1834c0000 + 405436
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000182cbf068 0x182cbd000 + 8296
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000182cbf210 0x182cbd000 + 8720
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000182ce8810 0x182ce0000 + 34832
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000182cd754c 0x182cbd000 + 107852
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000182cd7158 0x182cbd000 + 106840
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000182ce86e8 0x182ce0000 + 34536
9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183964cc4 0x18395c000 + 36036
10  GraphicsServices                0x0000000185810f84 0x185806000 + 44932
11  UIKit                           0x000000018d0bd5c4 0x18d04a000 + 472516
12  Yall                            0x000000010445944c 0x104454000 + 21580
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018348456c 0x183483000 + 5484

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001835b4d80 0x183592000 + 142720
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001836c6eec 0x1836c6000 + 3820
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001836c6b6c 0x1836c6000 + 2924

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001836c6b68 0x1836c6000 + 2920

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183593568 0x183592000 + 5480
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001835933e0 0x183592000 + 5088
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183a47108 0x18395c000 + 962824
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183a44cd4 0x18395c000 + 953556
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183964c58 0x18395c000 + 35928
5   Foundation                      0x0000000184399594 0x18438d000 + 50580
6   Foundation                      0x00000001843b89ac 0x18438d000 + 178604
7   UIKit                           0x000000018dc277a8 0x18d04a000 + 12441512
8   Foundation                      0x000000018449b0f4 0x18438d000 + 1106164
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001836c82b4 0x1836c6000 + 8884
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001836c8180 0x1836c6000 + 8576
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001836c6b74 0x1836c6000 + 2932

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001835b4d80 0x183592000 + 142720
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001836c6eec 0x1836c6000 + 3820
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001836c6b6c 0x1836c6000 + 2924

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001835b4d80 0x183592000 + 142720
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001836c6eec 0x1836c6000 + 3820
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001836c6b6c 0x1836c6000 + 2924

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001836c6b68 0x1836c6000 + 2920

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001836c6b68 0x1836c6000 + 2920

Thread 8 name:  AVAudioSession Notify Thread
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183593568 0x183592000 + 5480
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001835933e0 0x183592000 + 5088
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183a47108 0x18395c000 + 962824
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183a44cd4 0x18395c000 + 953556
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183964c58 0x18395c000 + 35928
5   AVFAudio                        0x00000001892cdcd4 0x189244000 + 564436
6   AVFAudio                        0x00000001892f8740 0x189244000 + 739136
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001836c82b4 0x1836c6000 + 8884
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001836c8180 0x1836c6000 + 8576
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001836c6b74 0x1836c6000 + 2932

Thread 9 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183593568 0x183592000 + 5480
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001835933e0 0x183592000 + 5088
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183a47108 0x18395c000 + 962824
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183a44cd4 0x18395c000 + 953556
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183964c58 0x18395c000 + 35928
5   CFNetwork                       0x0000000184253b08 0x184020000 + 2308872
6   Foundation                      0x000000018449b0f4 0x18438d000 + 1106164
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001836c82b4 0x1836c6000 + 8884
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001836c8180 0x1836c6000 + 8576
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001836c6b74 0x1836c6000 + 2932

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x00000001c02e57b7
    x4: 0x0000000182cdcafd   x5: 0x000000016b9ab4e0   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0xffffffffffffffec
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x00000001836cd5e0  x11: 0x0000000000000003
   x12: 0xffffffffffffffff  x13: 0x0000000000000001  x14: 0x000000018353953f  x15: 0x0000000000000010
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x00000000ffffffff  x18: 0xfffffff017e9925c  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x00000001b46eeb80  x21: 0x000000016b9ab4e0  x22: 0x0000000000000303  x23: 0x00000001b46eec60
   x24: 0x00000001c4001d90  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x0000000000000001  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x000000016b9abb38   fp: 0x000000016b9ab440   lr: 0x00000001836c92f8
    sp: 0x000000016b9ab410   pc: 0x00000001835b42e8 cpsr: 0x00000000

Binary Images:
0x104454000 - 0x104557fff Yall arm64  <95dc9e309fe836be9987d128e9be8c14> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F3EE3E40-C05D-45C7-83B4-124F597DB19A/Yall.app/Yall
0x1045c4000 - 0x1045f7fff AFNetworking arm64  <befb843e0e5238c5ae333ad6af659099> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F3EE3E40-C05D-45C7-83B4-124F597DB19A/Yall.app/Frameworks/AFNetworking.framework/AFNetworking
0x104614000 - 0x10462bfff Bolts arm64  <10b81bcdfc203e07b3016757bdcdb690> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F3EE3E40-C05D-45C7-83B4-124F597DB19A/Yall.app/Frameworks/Bolts.framework/Bolts
0x10463c000 - 0x10464ffff libswiftAVFoundation.dylib arm64  <ea096540bfd335119d4c1f597da34f2f> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F3EE3E40-C05D-45C7-83B4-124F597DB19A/Yall.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib
0x10465c000 - 0x10469bfff dyld arm64  <477a8a1f098b3a80860d656a3f4918ea> /usr/lib/dyld
0x1046f8000 - 0x10470ffff BoltsSwift arm64  <54546ecd15183db081a9bd388a4b28de> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F3EE3E40-C05D-45C7-83B4-124F597DB19A/Yall.app/Frameworks/BoltsSwift.framework/BoltsSwift
0x10471c000 - 0x104773fff FBSDKCoreKit arm64  <54bdddc4706b361c8de77875bb1959e7> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F3EE3E40-C05D-45C7-83B4-124F597DB19A/Yall.app/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit
0x1047a4000 - 0x1047bffff FBSDKLoginKit arm64  <b74d194b40b5331eac85c009b4db3f79> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F3EE3E40-C05D-45C7-83B4-124F597DB19A/Yall.app/Frameworks/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit
0x1047d0000 - 0x104833fff FBSDKShareKit arm64  <c4e7741aad143671b4719b0e7ab16086> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F3EE3E40-C05D-45C7-83B4-124F597DB19A/Yall.app/Frameworks/FBSDKShareKit.framework/FBSDKShareKit
0x104854000 - 0x10494ffff Parse arm64  <7a57a970c25c3844a73229d6ad79a3fa> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F3EE3E40-C05D-45C7-83B4-124F597DB19A/Yall.app/Frameworks/Parse.framework/Parse
0x1049ac000 - 0x1049cffff ParseLiveQuery arm64  <d00bb8ac711c3e92b8042a7b48922fb1> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F3EE3E40-C05D-45C7-83B4-124F597DB19A/Yall.app/Frameworks/ParseLiveQuery.framework/ParseLiveQuery
0x1049e0000 - 0x104a13fff Starscream arm64  <225cf65b66c63d53ab2c3561db4a8227> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F3EE3E40-C05D-45C7-83B4-124F597DB19A/Yall.app/Frameworks/Starscream.framework/Starscream
0x104a2c000 - 0x104da7fff libswiftCore.dylib arm64  <d49c1061edca3dbb98d1aefc461d47c9> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F3EE3E40-C05D-45C7-83B4-124F597DB19A/Yall.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
0x104e78000 - 0x104e83fff libswiftCoreAudio.dylib arm64  <19779a5debc932c5a86b23c64d041333> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F3EE3E40-C05D-45C7-83B4-124F597DB19A/Yall.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreAudio.dylib
0x104e90000 - 0x104e97fff libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib arm64  <68afe0804c2c3be6b7fae0a57fb10a85> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F3EE3E40-C05D-45C7-83B4-124F597DB19A/Yall.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib
0x104ea0000 - 0x104eaffff libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib arm64  <cb1c6c422a8a3cd997c5a317d9cdbee4> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F3EE3E40-C05D-45C7-83B4-124F597DB19A/Yall.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
0x104ec0000 - 0x104ec7fff libswiftCoreImage.dylib arm64  <df830999708f38468fd25493e1594210> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F3EE3E40-C05D-45C7-83B4-124F597DB19A/Yall.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib
0x104ed0000 - 0x104ed7fff libswiftCoreLocation.dylib arm64  <d55ac7f56d783583b65866631430c7d7> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F3EE3E40-C05D-45C7-83B4-124F597DB19A/Yall.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreLocation.dylib
0x104ee0000 - 0x104ee7fff libswiftCoreMedia.dylib arm64  <3e8ca8a84c6b3046a80b00c6e8c274d1> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F3EE3E40-C05D-45C7-83B4-124F597DB19A/Yall.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreMedia.dylib
0x104ef0000 - 0x104ef7fff libswiftDarwin.dylib arm64  <ff828b9ecc303cb6b742b2286ed74f73> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F3EE3E40-C05D-45C7-83B4-124F597DB19A/Yall.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib
0x104f04000 - 0x104f23fff libswiftDispatch.dylib arm64  <35ecfa5854a93eb5944b8f3279d7172a> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F3EE3E40-C05D-45C7-83B4-124F597DB19A/Yall.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib
0x104f3c000 - 0x105093fff libswiftFoundation.dylib arm64  <697dca62408431918a035904349d5c57> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F3EE3E40-C05D-45C7-83B4-124F597DB19A/Yall.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib
0x1050e4000 - 0x1050ebfff libswiftMapKit.dylib arm64  <c22450aa3c7b3791904961b3c5e23fc7> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F3EE3E40-C05D-45C7-83B4-124F597DB19A/Yall.app/Frameworks/libswiftMapKit.dylib
0x1050f4000 - 0x1050fbfff libswiftMetal.dylib arm64  <b3b47dd0ab023354bd57d0276eaa9ae5> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F3EE3E40-C05D-45C7-83B4-124F597DB19A/Yall.app/Frameworks/libswiftMetal.dylib
0x105104000 - 0x10510bfff libswiftObjectiveC.dylib arm64  <4caab770287c354e88ce634153ef89ff> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F3EE3E40-C05D-45C7-83B4-124F597DB19A/Yall.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
0x105118000 - 0x10511ffff libswiftPhotos.dylib arm64  <9863381219f63ccd8d5f442f79f667e1> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F3EE3E40-C05D-45C7-83B4-124F597DB19A/Yall.app/Frameworks/libswiftPhotos.dylib
0x105128000 - 0x10512ffff libswiftQuartzCore.dylib arm64  <ec21b18f2ba73678b764ee5100d64789> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F3EE3E40-C05D-45C7-83B4-124F597DB19A/Yall.app/Frameworks/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib
0x105138000 - 0x105143fff libswiftUIKit.dylib arm64  <9c1c66596c4b30358286e96e09e93e21> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F3EE3E40-C05D-45C7-83B4-124F597DB19A/Yall.app/Frameworks/libswiftUIKit.dylib
0x105150000 - 0x10517ffff libswiftsimd.dylib arm64  <1069c93f187734b7af88a5683bdfe839> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F3EE3E40-C05D-45C7-83B4-124F597DB19A/Yall.app/Frameworks/libswiftsimd.dylib
0x105190000 - 0x105197fff libswiftos.dylib arm64  <c833b9c78e2f375ebe50a76f426d063a> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F3EE3E40-C05D-45C7-83B4-124F597DB19A/Yall.app/Frameworks/libswiftos.dylib
0x1051a0000 - 0x1051abfff libswiftCoreData.dylib arm64  <7d47ebd211bd332eadfa0994dc574c27> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F3EE3E40-C05D-45C7-83B4-124F597DB19A/Yall.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreData.dylib
0x182c61000 - 0x182c62fff libSystem.B.dylib arm64  <a9f67ca8b7963c699078236267472fb0> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x182c63000 - 0x182cbcfff libc++.1.dylib arm64  <aee157a049663aa88c4e928768cfd553> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x182cbd000 - 0x182cddfff libc++abi.dylib arm64  <b4f54419327f3bfea747549b84dad328> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x182ce0000 - 0x18339bfff libobjc.A.dylib arm64  <3a9d464322eb3285bc88fabf7cec20ed> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x18339c000 - 0x1833a0fff libcache.dylib arm64  <474a695498903419b648b834067fac4e> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x1833a1000 - 0x1833acfff libcommonCrypto.dylib arm64  <f3a95fbdb7a037879160ae9e0ee14c37> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x1833ad000 - 0x1833b0fff libcompiler_rt.dylib arm64  <502de73c3e0c3ba78280e6164fe5728c> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x1833b1000 - 0x1833b8fff libcopyfile.dylib arm64  <b8c962560a1b3b639d562541d32f5960> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x1833b9000 - 0x18341cfff libcorecrypto.dylib arm64  <db41a416fa083812bcafad6b888b152e> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x18341d000 - 0x183482fff libdispatch.dylib arm64  <37135142d2043b5492d7a49be678b9ae> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x183483000 - 0x18349dfff libdyld.dylib arm64  <4f57dfca63a93930a57d2cea89307b01> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x18349e000 - 0x18349efff liblaunch.dylib arm64  <ca90373a022d3c38ac7ecd736c13bf9b> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x18349f000 - 0x1834a4fff libmacho.dylib arm64  <25640409947b3e20b1135068c80d8609> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x1834a5000 - 0x1834a6fff libremovefile.dylib arm64  <848fca02e8d930fd8659eb188d9bcedd> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x1834a7000 - 0x1834befff libsystem_asl.dylib arm64  <255a36a954553a278ef2c8711ab62532> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
0x1834bf000 - 0x1834bffff libsystem_blocks.dylib arm64  <cbdfd75e23c43610991dc81d325587ea> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x1834c0000 - 0x18353dfff libsystem_c.dylib arm64  <2c43d27314963feb8966491ea64cf5a9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x18353e000 - 0x183542fff libsystem_configuration.dylib arm64  <897ce699a6d73797810d7fe5ceef37d7> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
0x183543000 - 0x183548fff libsystem_containermanager.dylib arm64  <ae270ac5b9613cfcb5a6ada4520b8a8b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_containermanager.dylib
0x183549000 - 0x18354afff libsystem_coreservices.dylib arm64  <c897206125f13042a7f62767de020ae9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
0x18354b000 - 0x18354cfff libsystem_darwin.dylib arm64  <fc17590f3b6f3e2280aa164fe705e624> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_darwin.dylib
0x18354d000 - 0x183553fff libsystem_dnssd.dylib arm64  <2fdef17227d13f49929b104ec635667c> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x183554000 - 0x183591fff libsystem_info.dylib arm64  <c20c44a2d57b330f9931ba840195ee45> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x183592000 - 0x1835bafff libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64  <6ca465bb9c013f9ab3fb24dd16418142> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x1835bb000 - 0x1835e8fff libsystem_m.dylib arm64  <a75c726ec49b3f48b83593be165afcfa> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
0x1835e9000 - 0x183603fff libsystem_malloc.dylib arm64  <cce71425b3483c5fa3718246e8e27ed2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
0x183604000 - 0x1836a4fff libsystem_network.dylib arm64  <cac262c32d6938abb9075481187087c4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x1836a5000 - 0x1836b0fff libsystem_networkextension.dylib arm64  <40f740c2ec9b37cebe6043eecbd1927d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
0x1836b1000 - 0x1836bbfff libsystem_notify.dylib arm64  <c204b6b2ef2d38669fb985bc64f26a6b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x1836bc000 - 0x1836c5fff libsystem_platform.dylib arm64  <1fd32dd6f1da3029ae0fe5875eaceb94> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
0x1836c6000 - 0x1836d5fff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64  <2f9b440f88eb3cedb786b4b98586d78f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
0x1836d6000 - 0x1836d9fff libsystem_sandbox.dylib arm64  <001e1a85480c3b07b93861fe7e69843b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x1836da000 - 0x1836e1fff libsystem_symptoms.dylib arm64  <56e7c311193139968b729073897fbdc6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib
0x1836e2000 - 0x1836f5fff libsystem_trace.dylib arm64  <8b98d3487b6e3b72863670eb57c3b4ff> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
0x1836f6000 - 0x1836fbfff libunwind.dylib arm64  <a9da0d0735093dc38005623608c0f71e> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x1836fc000 - 0x1836fcfff libvminterpose.dylib arm64  <c1577063af17384b8091f9923960a1f1> /usr/lib/system/libvminterpose.dylib
0x1836fd000 - 0x183727fff libxpc.dylib arm64  <1732d812fa793d159965e668759a42df> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x183728000 - 0x183949fff libicucore.A.dylib arm64  <32c272e1e9f735aba4c16a17580f13e3> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x18394a000 - 0x18395bfff libz.1.dylib arm64  <c402ff63470b34df8634f2078cd151e1> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x18395c000 - 0x183cf1fff CoreFoundation arm64  <846f4b1542383c98991c1314902e3d72> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x183cf2000 - 0x183d02fff libbsm.0.dylib arm64  <b7a56e43a852351d8a2dab94c7fc04e6> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x183d03000 - 0x183d03fff libenergytrace.dylib arm64  <6adeca3b70ed33dda70a16353c5ef6ce> /usr/lib/libenergytrace.dylib
0x183d04000 - 0x183d89fff IOKit arm64  <938f5f32ece43551a651b777bd44d431> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x183d8a000 - 0x183e73fff libxml2.2.dylib arm64  <33530216f58333d993d4acb846c63aac> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x183e74000 - 0x183e81fff libbz2.1.0.dylib arm64  <35c6ddde076638589f755656ac0058ce> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x183e82000 - 0x183e9afff liblzma.5.dylib arm64  <7d5815f117103d15a67fd30b3375b11b> /usr/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
0x183e9b000 - 0x183ff8fff libsqlite3.dylib arm64  <eac933b033d43444ae182e2d7de6137f> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x183ff9000 - 0x18401ffff libMobileGestalt.dylib arm64  <dc43249a916a3294a98ae31871591dd9> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x184020000 - 0x18438cfff CFNetwork arm64  <1b8095865d8a3b84a9cbe0d5d0354fc1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x18438d000 - 0x184688fff Foundation arm64  <dad046ce90513de69c6ca86d7184b7c2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x184689000 - 0x184777fff Security arm64  <11c28a235f0d34a483d4c0c6d3a72617> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x184778000 - 0x1847e4fff SystemConfiguration arm64  <e4021e13feec30af8e612a49060b1ad1> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x1847e5000 - 0x18481bfff libCRFSuite.dylib arm64  <faed949ffe90353091a2916aef415302> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x18481c000 - 0x18481cfff libapple_crypto.dylib arm64  <7b69ce788b6f3bd581d76b857760c614> /usr/lib/libapple_crypto.dylib
0x18481d000 - 0x184833fff libapple_nghttp2.dylib arm64  <ff88135792b639679509b309f0c0cad9> /usr/lib/libapple_nghttp2.dylib
0x184834000 - 0x18485dfff libarchive.2.dylib arm64  <957aea53942d3afc91420044f6ae5112> /usr/lib/libarchive.2.dylib
0x18485e000 - 0x18490ffff libboringssl.dylib arm64  <a515a4c41d7337dd85ed1db0cb3d1a09> /usr/lib/libboringssl.dylib
0x184910000 - 0x184927fff libcoretls.dylib arm64  <c2287d06413f32c2aee0e6c3313d98c7> /usr/lib/libcoretls.dylib
0x184928000 - 0x184929fff libcoretls_cfhelpers.dylib arm64  <79276edd953836b698947c5db28c83ad> /usr/lib/libcoretls_cfhelpers.dylib
0x18492a000 - 0x18492bfff liblangid.dylib arm64  <11d94ede5ab1300a820d96e3374f53fa> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x18492c000 - 0x1849fffff libnetwork.dylib arm64  <e4a37ecffec3327bb37e3fd427c92b87> /usr/lib/libnetwork.dylib
0x184a00000 - 0x184a32fff libpcap.A.dylib arm64  <419a8dd2325a326c81b4b02d849ce562> /usr/lib/libpcap.A.dylib
0x184a33000 - 0x184a67fff libusrtcp.dylib arm64  <227ec64866e53676828e76f89c1e4928> /usr/lib/libusrtcp.dylib
0x184a68000 - 0x184a71fff IOSurface arm64  <76764bfa34e8365e8263c8ec57868e70> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x184a72000 - 0x184b17fff libBLAS.dylib arm64  <05ecdd31f9573a069c0e8b3d610bbc3f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x184b18000 - 0x184e47fff libLAPACK.dylib arm64  <3e55f73c8a4c329d8bb7f5e58ed687c3> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x184e48000 - 0x1850b4fff vImage arm64  <7fabce5d1fe83c38aa998440146eb09b> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x1850b5000 - 0x1850c6fff libSparseBLAS.dylib arm64  <88335b280db13b3d812ee89998bc363c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libSparseBLAS.dylib
0x1850c7000 - 0x1850ebfff libvMisc.dylib arm64  <20da313fe2343db189a04c72928eb120> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
```

Comment: first you need to re symbolicate this crash log then you will find relevant information, at this moment you only have address memory cryptic information

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to symbolicate crash log Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855389/how-to-symbolicate-crash-log-xcode)

Comment: @Will It is a duplicate of that question, but the answer is relevant for Xcode 5 (we are now on 9). It's not guaranteed that the answer is still valid.