# Understanding Xcode Device Log Crashes

Tags: ios, xcode, crash-log

I am a relatively new developer and would like some assistance. My app does not crash when I have it hooked up via Xcode. However, when I try to run it again the next day (launching from my phone), it crashes when trying to open it. I am currently debugging the situation and am unsure how to proceed.

I'm having troubles with understanding how a device log crashes work. I was able to get to my device's crashes in Xcode via Window>Device and Simulators>View Device Logs>All Logs. I am able to understand that having an Exception type of "EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)" means that I force unwrap a nil value.  I am unsure how through looking at the log (or any other method) that I can locate in my code where this is happening. How can I locate in all my files where this is causing a crash?

```
Date/Time:           2018-04-05 14:33:48.7121 -0500
Launch Time:         2018-04-05 14:33:47.8058 -0500
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.3 (15E216)
Baseband Version:    1.04.16
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000104177ff8
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  1

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180d07e08 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180d07c80 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018124ae40 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181248908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1568
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181168da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
5   GraphicsServices                0x000000018314b020 GSEventRunModal + 100
6   UIKit                           0x000000018b14978c UIApplicationMain + 236
7   &me                             0x0000000102cd00e4 0x102bac000 + 1196260
8   libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000180bf9fc0 start + 4

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: NSOperationQueue 0x1d4224f80 (QOS: UNSPECIFIED)
Thread 1 Crashed:
0   libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000104177ff8 0x103fd0000 + 1736696
1   libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000104177ff8 0x103fd0000 + 1736696
2   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001040182b8 0x103fd0000 + 295608
3   &me                             0x0000000102c9576c 0x102bac000 + 956268
4   &me                             0x0000000102c95cbc 0x102bac000 + 957628
5   CFNetwork                       0x0000000181831c1c __75-[__NSURLSessionLocal taskForClass:request:uploadFile:bodyData:completion:]_block_invoke + 32
6   CFNetwork                       0x000000018184a93c __49-[__NSCFLocalSessionTask _task_onqueue_didFinish]_block_invoke + 152
7   Foundation                      0x0000000181ccae88 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16
8   Foundation                      0x0000000181c0c8d0 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 72
9   Foundation                      0x0000000181c0bcac -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 848
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180b94ae4 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180bd0b0c _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$armv81 + 216
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180b94ae4 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180bd0b0c _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$armv81 + 216
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180bd0a00 dispatch_block_perform$VARIANT$armv81 + 104
15  Foundation                      0x0000000181ccc750 __NSOQSchedule_f + 376
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180b94ae4 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180bd17a8 _dispatch_continuation_pop$VARIANT$armv81 + 416
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180bd0180 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke$VARIANT$armv81 + 596
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180bd63a4 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 592
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180bd60f0 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ec7fac _pthread_wqthread + 1176
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ec7b08 start_wqthread + 4
```

Comment: You need to symbolicate the crash log so you can see the exact line of your code causing the crash. Until then, no one can really help with the issue.

Comment: I symbolicated the crash log using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30431450/9330847) and now have a bunch of binary images listed with the same device log crash as above. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To understand the crash log you can go through the following apple documentation. This is the best explanation I found so far.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html