# React Native APP Crashes after loaded for few seconds only in iOS

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

Crash Report

> libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
>
> ```
> 0x7fff523bc7f0 <+0>:  movl   $0x2000148, %eax          ; imm = 0x2000148 
> 0x7fff523bc7f5 <+5>:  movq   %rcx, %r10
> 0x7fff523bc7f8 <+8>:  syscall
> ```
>
> ->  0x7fff523bc7fa <+10>: jae    0x7fff523bc804            ; <+20>
>       0x7fff523bc7fc <+12>: movq   %rax, %rdi
>       0x7fff523bc7ff <+15>: jmp    0x7fff523b6a89            ; cerror_nocancel
>       0x7fff523bc804 <+20>: retq
>       0x7fff523bc805 <+21>: nop
>       0x7fff523bc806 <+22>: nop
>       0x7fff523bc807 <+23>: nop

Problem only in IOS and it runs successfully on debug mode but problem is only when we changed it to Release

Comment: There's no useful information in the crash report you posted. You need [the symbolicated version of it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25927122/1445366).

Comment: How have you resolved it? I am facing the same issue