# How to resolve crash log for rejected app?

Tags: swift, xcode

I try to publish new version of my app, I already do it at least 10 times without any problem but now they give me logs where app crashed but I don't know how to resolve it because if I understand it crash on iPad 11, iOS 13.3 and when I try on simulator it works, also works on real iPhone device. Here is log they sent me:

```
{"app_name":"TestApp","timestamp":"2020-01-19 12:53:55.40 -0800","app_version":"1.1.8","slice_uuid":"c9785107-598f-39c9-8618-d899d9d3e224","adam_id":1420789522,"build_version":"31","bundleID":"com.test","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 13.3 (17C54)","incident_id":"C854E183-BEE6-4DAB-AA04-C5DBF1371CE1","name":"TestApp"}
Incident Identifier: C854E183-BEE6-4DAB-AA04-C5DBF1371CE1
CrashReporter Key:   04fc8ede758d6f5213f351e2f6a3fc5288398189
Hardware Model:      iPad11,3
Process:             TestApp [20966]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A0043344-79CC-4727-BFED-A81F5E3C8E93/TestAPP.app/TestAPP
Identifier:          com.test
Version:             31 (1.1.8)
AppStoreTools:       11C29
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.test [5248]


Date/Time:           2020-01-19 12:53:54.7229 -0800
Launch Time:         2020-01-19 12:53:53.8731 -0800
OS Version:          iPhone OS 13.3 (17C54)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    n/a
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x190e7696c 0x190b8f028 0x190d6614c 0x1948d1860 0x1948d1b48 0x1944ab24c 0x1944ab480 0x19444600c 0x19491aba8 0x104f3a740 0x104f3a800 0x194beccf8 0x1944ab24c 0x1944ab480 0x19444600c 0x194bebfec 0x19491ad60 0x194858a34 0x194beccf8 0x1944ab24c 0x19444600c 0x194bf0ea4 0x1944ab24c 0x1944ab480 0x19444600c 0x194bebdd0 0x194beea08 0x1950c1050 0x1950c0ee0 0x194f63a78 0x194f63ff0 0x194f62724 0x1946fb158 0x194bac9f8 0x1946fbc90 0x1946fb6c0 0x1946fbaac 0x1946fb330 0x1946ffab0 0x194bc687c 0x194ad8c9c 0x194bc6834 0x1946ff7c8 0x194bc671c 0x1946ff624 0x1945679a0 0x194566464 0x1945676d0 0x194f60c10 0x194afab9c 0x196058e10 0x19607faa0 0x196063ef4 0x19607f734 0x190b1bfd8 0x190b1ed1c 0x1960a6254 0x1960a5f00 0x1960a646c 0x190df2108 0x190df205c 0x190df1818 0x190dec694 0x190debf40 0x19b069534 0x194f64a60 0x10492644c 0x190c6ae18)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000190c60efc 0x190c3b000 + 155388
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190b808b8 0x190b7e000 + 10424
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000190b10af4 0x190a9a000 + 486132
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000190b10a80 0x190a9a000 + 486016
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000190c283c8 0x190c27000 + 5064
5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000190c285c0 0x190c27000 + 5568
6   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000190b8f308 0x190b89000 + 25352
7   TestAPP                         0x0000000104f55b18 0x10491c000 + 6527768
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000190c35634 0x190c27000 + 58932
9   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000190c355c0 0x190c27000 + 58816
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000190b1bfec 0x190b19000 + 12268
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000190b1ed1c 0x190b19000 + 23836
12  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001960a6254 0x19604c000 + 369236
13  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001960a5f00 0x19604c000 + 368384
14  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001960a646c 0x19604c000 + 369772
15  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000190df2108 0x190d44000 + 712968
16  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000190df205c 0x190d44000 + 712796
17  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000190df1818 0x190d44000 + 710680
18  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000190dec694 0x190d44000 + 689812
19  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000190debf40 0x190d44000 + 687936
20  GraphicsServices                0x000000019b069534 0x19b066000 + 13620
21  UIKitCore                       0x0000000194f64a60 0x194521000 + 10762848
22  TestAPP                         0x000000010492644c 0x10491c000 + 42060
23  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000190c6ae18 0x190c6a000 + 3608

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190b879e0 0x190b7e000 + 39392

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190b879e0 0x190b7e000 + 39392

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190b879e0 0x190b7e000 + 39392

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190b879e0 0x190b7e000 + 39392

Thread 5 name:  Dispatch queue: com.google.fira.worker
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000190c638dc 0x190c3b000 + 166108
1   libsqlite3.dylib                0x0000000192acaf18 0x192aa3000 + 163608
2   libsqlite3.dylib                0x0000000192ac9b8c 0x192aa3000 + 158604
3   libsqlite3.dylib                0x0000000192ac8d38 0x192aa3000 + 154936
4   libsqlite3.dylib                0x0000000192ae84b4 0x192aa3000 + 283828
5   libsqlite3.dylib                0x0000000192ae61a4 0x192aa3000 + 274852
6   TestAPP                         0x00000001051cea58 0x10491c000 + 9120344
7   TestAPP                         0x00000001051ce9c8 0x10491c000 + 9120200
8   TestAPP                         0x00000001051cbcec 0x10491c000 + 9108716
9   TestAPP                         0x00000001051caf8c 0x10491c000 + 9105292
10  TestAPP                         0x00000001051cb868 0x10491c000 + 9107560
11  TestAPP                         0x000000010519d1c4 0x10491c000 + 8917444
12  TestAPP                         0x000000010519b7a4 0x10491c000 + 8910756
13  TestAPP                         0x0000000105190cc4 0x10491c000 + 8867012
14  TestAPP                         0x00000001051a20f8 0x10491c000 + 8937720
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000190b1bfd8 0x190b19000 + 12248
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000190b1d6c0 0x190b19000 + 18112
17  TestAPP                         0x00000001051a1ce4 0x10491c000 + 8936676
18  TestAPP                         0x00000001051a185c 0x10491c000 + 8935516
19  TestAPP                         0x00000001051ba638 0x10491c000 + 9037368
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000190b1ab7c 0x190b19000 + 7036
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000190b1bfd8 0x190b19000 + 12248
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000190b22450 0x190b19000 + 37968
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000190b22e7c 0x190b19000 + 40572
24  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000190b2bf20 0x190b19000 + 77600
25  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190b816d0 0x190b7e000 + 14032
26  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190b879e8 0x190b7e000 + 39400

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000190c3ec04 0x190c3b000 + 15364
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000190c3e020 0x190c3b000 + 12320
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000190df1964 0x190d44000 + 711012
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000190dec7fc 0x190d44000 + 690172
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000190debf40 0x190d44000 + 687936
5   Foundation                      0x00000001911313b0 0x191129000 + 33712
6   Foundation                      0x0000000191131288 0x191129000 + 33416
7   UIKitCore                       0x000000019500023c 0x194521000 + 11399740
8   Foundation                      0x0000000191130014 0x191129000 + 28692
9   Foundation                      0x000000019126ba7c 0x191129000 + 1321596
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190b7f840 0x190b7e000 + 6208
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190b879f4 0x190b7e000 + 39412

Thread 7 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000190c3ec04 0x190c3b000 + 15364
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000190c3e020 0x190c3b000 + 12320
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000190df1964 0x190d44000 + 711012
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000190dec7fc 0x190d44000 + 690172
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000190debf40 0x190d44000 + 687936
5   CFNetwork                       0x00000001940de568 0x1940dd000 + 5480
6   Foundation                      0x0000000191130014 0x191129000 + 28692
7   Foundation                      0x000000019126ba7c 0x191129000 + 1321596
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190b7f840 0x190b7e000 + 6208
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190b879f4 0x190b7e000 + 39412

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190b879e0 0x190b7e000 + 39392

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190b879e0 0x190b7e000 + 39392

Thread 10 name:  com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.MachExceptionServer
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000190c3ec04 0x190c3b000 + 15364
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000190c3e020 0x190c3b000 + 12320
2   TestAPP                         0x0000000104f43788 0x10491c000 + 6453128
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190b7f840 0x190b7e000 + 6208
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190b879f4 0x190b7e000 + 39412

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190b879e0 0x190b7e000 + 39392

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190b879e0 0x190b7e000 + 39392

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190b879e0 0x190b7e000 + 39392

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000989680   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000700
    x8: 0x00000000000005b9   x9: 0xf7d46cce9088dc31  x10: 0x00000000000003e8  x11: 0x0000000000000003
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x000000000000003d  x14: 0x0000000000000010  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x00000001cdcd6f10  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x0000000000000507  x21: 0x0000000105a71920  x22: 0x0000000000000007  x23: 0x00000001053f7080
   x24: 0x0000000000000001  x25: 0x0000000000000001  x26: 0x000000016b4e2ca0  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x000000016b4e3b10   fp: 0x000000016b4e23a0   lr: 0x0000000190b808b8
    sp: 0x000000016b4e2380   pc: 0x0000000190c60efc cpsr: 0x40000000
   esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault

Binary Images:
0x10491c000 - 0x1054f7fff TestAPP arm64  <c9785107598f39c98618d899d9d3e224> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/A0043344-79CC-4727-BFED-A81F5E3C8E93/TestAPP.app/TestAPP
0x1057e4000 - 0x10585bfff Alamofire arm64  <e5f28f57afb5399bb87fd779a6125b44> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/A0043344-79CC-4727-BFED-A81F5E3C8E93/TestAPP.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
0x105888000 - 0x10588ffff Alamofire_SwiftyJSON arm64  <0090a54c72ad3b898fd16dd44b3c06e2> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/A0043344-79CC-4727-BFED-A81F5E3C8E93/TestAPP.app/Frameworks/Alamofire_SwiftyJSON.framework/Alamofire_SwiftyJSON
0x10589c000 - 0x1058b3fff Bolts arm64  <759fb69630e53d1394e57c007130fd42> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/A0043344-79CC-4727-BFED-A81F5E3C8E93/TestAPP.app/Frameworks/Bolts.framework/Bolts
0x1058c8000 - 0x1058f7fff Cache arm64  <fcefc3d78f8b372ea1d7610c04b3f70d> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/A0043344-79CC-4727-BFED-A81F5E3C8E93/TestAPP.app/Frameworks/Cache.framework/Cache
0x105910000 - 0x105953fff CryptoSwift arm64  <6f12cc0df4193739bb9076a752bc99b9> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/A0043344-79CC-4727-BFED-A81F5E3C8E93/TestAPP.app/Frameworks/CryptoSwift.framework/CryptoSwift
0x10597c000 - 0x105997fff FBSDKLoginKit arm64  <a2fa6911f5033023903b8ce26950c785> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/A0043344-79CC-4727-BFED-A81F5E3C8E93/TestAPP.app/Frameworks/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit
0x1059ac000 - 0x1059d3fff GTMSessionFetcher arm64  <47c927682a453da68f2c1d43a8240cf3> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/A0043344-79CC-4727-BFED-A81F5E3C8E93/TestAPP.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher
0x1059ec000 - 0x1059f3fff GoogleToolboxForMac arm64  <579dd0d8a6e530fe82ae4075c313c995> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/A0043344-79CC-4727-BFED-A81F5E3C8E93/TestAPP.app/Frameworks/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac
0x105a00000 - 0x105a67fff dyld arm64e  <651eb4d8a0f03c97a0c46a8f6fc17a56> /usr/lib/dyld
0x105ae4000 - 0x105b53fff FBSDKCoreKit arm64  <83e1c46f87433649be887cc849b3508c> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/A0043344-79CC-4727-BFED-A81F5E3C8E93/TestAPP.app/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit
0x105b98000 - 0x105baffff GoogleUtilities arm64  <fb765b407a2038bd848604fabc0f9e68> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/A0043344-79CC-4727-BFED-A81F5E3C8E93/TestAPP.app/Frameworks/GoogleUtilities.framework/GoogleUtilities
0x105bc4000 - 0x105bd7fff Imaginary arm64  <e445914a470830a3be528ac0a531191d> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/A0043344-79CC-4727-BFED-A81F5E3C8E93/TestAPP.app/Frameworks/Imaginary.framework/Imaginary
0x105be8000 - 0x105bf3fff LKAlertController arm64  <03b9c67ede0b39ffbbb3381a2453eb57> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/A0043344-79CC-4727-BFED-A81F5E3C8E93/TestAPP.app/Frameworks/LKAlertController.framework/LKAlertController
0x105c04000 - 0x105c27fff Lightbox arm64  <711f31a18cef32ba85d9b6ec16c26597> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/A0043344-79CC-4727-BFED-A81F5E3C8E93/TestAPP.app/Frameworks/Lightbox.framework/Lightbox
0x105c40000 - 0x1060abfff Mapbox arm64  <6fb225c506333b94bd0bb852550cd50f> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/A0043344-79CC-4727-BFED-A81F5E3C8E93/TestAPP.app/Frameworks/Mapbox.framework/Mapbox
0x106128000 - 0x106153fff MapboxMobileEvents arm64  <1d205c1679b731a5bf418e76e08dd1e9> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/A0043344-79CC-4727-BFED-A81F5E3C8E93/TestAPP.app/Frameworks/MapboxMobileEvents.framework/MapboxMobileEvents
0x106174000 - 0x10617bfff MapboxPlugins arm64  <ba334f3f6e743d00a5d98cc91c8b97f9> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/A0043344-79CC-4727-BFED-A81F5E3C8E93/TestAPP.app/Frameworks/MapboxPlugins.framework/MapboxPlugins
0x106188000 - 0x1061affff NVActivityIndicatorView arm64  <f5acfb135a2f397dbb4c77725ab844eb> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/A0043344-79CC-4727-BFED-A81F5E3C8E93/TestAPP.app/Frameworks/NVActivityIndicatorView.framework/NVActivityIndicatorView
0x1061c4000 - 0x1061e7fff SDWebImage arm64  <bc71c29099f73ac2868066ac506b354c> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/A0043344-79CC-4727-BFED-A81F5E3C8E93/TestAPP.app/Frameworks/SDWebImage.framework/SDWebImage
0x106200000 - 0x106213fff SVProgressHUD arm64  <5f52cc39c5063db781bc5556cfd347fd> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/A0043344-79CC-4727-BFED-A81F5E3C8E93/TestAPP.app/Frameworks/SVProgressHUD.framework/SVProgressHUD
0x106224000 - 0x106247fff SwiftyJSON arm64  <867085647f5734e888fe8353f557aa4c> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/A0043344-79CC-4727-BFED-A81F5E3C8E93/TestAPP.app/Frameworks/SwiftyJSON.framework/SwiftyJSON
0x106258000 - 0x10628bfff TwitterCore arm64  <e43df3193b993bb382fe7cee61fcee24> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/A0043344-79CC-4727-BFED-A81F5E3C8E93/TestAPP.app/Frameworks/TwitterCore.framework/TwitterCore
0x1062ac000 - 0x106387fff TwitterKit arm64  <21064ef2227b30f28a4d6bd8939f12bb> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/A0043344-79CC-4727-BFED-A81F5E3C8E93/TestAPP.app/Frameworks/TwitterKit.framework/TwitterKit
0x1063f8000 - 0x1064d3fff grpc arm64  <30e2831db1773d8291b3505ac827be7b> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/A0043344-79CC-4727-BFED-A81F5E3C8E93/TestAPP.app/Frameworks/grpc.framework/grpc
0x106548000 - 0x10657bfff grpcpp arm64  <c413af7a4f5934589e14fb369ac31bfd> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/A0043344-79CC-4727-BFED-A81F5E3C8E93/TestAPP.app/Frameworks/grpcpp.framework/grpcpp
0x1065a4000 - 0x1065d7fff leveldb arm64  <acea470904ba3091aa0e2707fb884bc4> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/A0043344-79CC-4727-BFED-A81F5E3C8E93/TestAPP.app/Frameworks/leveldb.framework/leveldb
0x1065f4000 - 0x1065fffff nanopb arm64  <4efb5150777b3c7b9c29343938240a86> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/A0043344-79CC-4727-BFED-A81F5E3C8E93/TestAPP.app/Frameworks/nanopb.framework/nanopb
0x10660c000 - 0x1066e7fff openssl_grpc arm64  <5e574490cbe53ce9b14f5bf05f7c0bad> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/A0043344-79CC-4727-BFED-A81F5E3C8E93/TestAPP.app/Frameworks/openssl_grpc.framework/openssl_grpc
0x106748000 - 0x106797fff protobuf arm64  <6cfbc89f0ddb312cbc45f5520c1caf91> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/A0043344-79CC-4727-BFED-A81F5E3C8E93/TestAPP.app/Frameworks/protobuf.framework/protobuf
0x108628000 - 0x108633fff libobjc-trampolines.dylib arm64e  <028df612175838e498958fd8c6a9a03c> /usr/lib/libobjc-trampolines.dylib
```

...

EOF

Comment: You need to symbolicate the log, see also here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2151/_index.html

Comment: I just download txt logs from apple and rename it to .crash and just open it with xcode but there is nothing valuable in it. No line code or func name where it crash. Or maybe I don't symbolicate on right way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to symbolicate crash log Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855389/how-to-symbolicate-crash-log-xcode)

Comment: Still I get only hex addresses ...

Comment: After Download Debug Symbols I get two visible classes in crash but no code line or func name that make crash