# iOS 10 AVPlayer crash when dealloc

Tags: ios, avplayer

I got a crash when using AVPlayer to play a remote audio. The App crash on main thread. The crash log is below:

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001806a7014 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018076f450 pthread_kill + 112
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018061b49c __abort + 144
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018061b40c __abort + 0
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001800e52d4 __cxa_bad_cast + 0
5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000180102cc0 default_unexpected_handler+ 126144 () + 0
6   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000180110844 _objc_terminate+ 34884 () + 124
7   FanXing                         0x0000000103712edc 0x10007c000 + 57241308
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001800ff66c std::__terminate(void (*)+ 112236 ()) + 16
9   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001800ff234 __cxa_rethrow + 144
10  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018011071c objc_exception_rethrow + 44
11  Foundation                      0x0000000182154644 NSKVODeallocate + 380
12  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001816ca36c -[__NSSingleObjectArrayI dealloc] + 44
13  AVFoundation                    0x0000000188e166b0 -[AVPlayer dealloc] + 696
14  libsystem_blocks.dylib          0x00000001805b7a28 _Block_release + 144
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001805621bc _dispatch_client_callout + 16
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180566d68 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1000
17  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181686810 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
18  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001816843fc __CFRunLoopRun + 1660
19  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001815b22b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
20  GraphicsServices                0x0000000183066198 GSEventRunModal + 180
21  UIKit                           0x00000001875f97fc -[UIApplication _run] + 684
22  UIKit                           0x00000001875f4534 UIApplicationMain + 208
23  FanXing                         0x00000001004c248c 0x10007c000 + 4482188
24  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001805955b8 start + 4
```

Comment: Please show the rest of the crash log and your code where the crash happens. (You will need to symbolicate the crash log first.)

Comment: How to symbolicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855389/how-to-symbolicate-crash-log-xcode