# Symbolcate Crash Reports from Apple App Store Review

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, crash, app-store-connect

After submitting my app for Test Flight review, I received a message containing a crash report as a .txt file. I was unable to replicate the crash, so I'd like to symbolcate this report, or at least determine what might have caused the crash.

How can I symbolcate a crash report given to me by Apple?

```
Thread 6 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.background-qos
Thread 6 Crashed:
0   My App's Name       0x00000001003a5358 0x100378000 + 185176
1   My App's Name       0x00000001003a5358 0x100378000 + 185176
2   My App's Name       0x00000001003a5bb0 0x100378000 + 187312
3   My App's Name       0x00000001003b5ee4 0x100378000 + 253668
4   My App's Name       0x00000001003a167c 0x100378000 + 169596
5   My App's Name       0x00000001003a49b4 0x100378000 + 182708
6   My App's Name       0x00000001003c7be4 0x100378000 + 326628
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001961c924c 0x1961c7000 + 8780
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001961cadb0 0x1961c7000 + 15792
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001961dba68 0x1961c7000 + 84584
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001961dc120 0x1961c7000 + 86304
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e13497d8 0x1e1346000 + 14296
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e135076c 0x1e1346000 + 42860
```

Comment: You'll need the dsym file to symbolicate it. See this page for all the info you need: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing_issues_using_crash_reports_and_device_logs/adding_identifiable_symbol_names_to_a_crash_report

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to symbolicate crash log Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855389/how-to-symbolicate-crash-log-xcode)