# ionic - iOS app crashing on testflight installs

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, testflight

I have a problem with my app. When I try to navigate to the exact screen in my app, sometimes the app crashes.
It appears only in versions available via TestFlight.
It happens, when I try to navigate from one screen to another.

App is developed in ionic -> `@ionic-native/core": "^5.27.0"`

The log from the app crash is available below.
Any ideas about the potential problem/soluton?
Thanks in advance.

```
Incident Identifier: 5B232F09-BA4D-46D8-9158-0CE46A1C52B1
Beta Identifier:     26923487-77E7-44B3-A0E0-B6FB733AF1FC
Hardware Model:      iPhone13,2
Process:             App [9902]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B7BF1A34-DD89-4CD9-9DB2-E9FB8E7421A5/App.app/App
Identifier:          xx
Version:             35 (1.0.35)
AppStoreTools:       12E262
AppVariant:          1:iPhone13,2:14
Beta:                YES
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           xx


Date/Time:           2021-04-30 11:41:55.7013 +0200
Launch Time:         2021-04-30 11:38:47.5383 +0200
OS Version:          iPhone OS 14.5 (18E199)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    1.62.11
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  6

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x18cb965b4 0x1a16157a8 0x18ca98258 0x18de5f6e4 0x197e0486c 0x197e7aec4 0x18c7837ec 0x18c792d2c 0x18c792784 0x197e7a470 0x197e79af0 0x197e6b458 0x197e6b21c 0x1025c9ab0 0x18c781a54 0x18c7837ec 0x18c786938 0x18c794fb0 0x18c7957a8 0x1d86ce768 0x1d86d574c)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bac844fc 0x1bac80000 + 17660
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bac83884 0x1bac80000 + 14468
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018cb0fd10 0x18ca6d000 + 666896
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018cb09bb0 0x18ca6d000 + 641968
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018cb091c0 0x18ca6d000 + 639424
5   GraphicsServices                0x00000001a40f1734 0x1a40ee000 + 14132
6   UIKitCore                       0x000000018f5777e4 0x18e9ad000 + 12363748
7   UIKitCore                       0x000000018f57d054 0x18e9ad000 + 12386388
8   App                             0x00000001024989ec 0x102490000 + 35308
9   libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018c7c5cf8 0x18c7c4000 + 7416

Thread 1 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bac844fc 0x1bac80000 + 17660
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bac83884 0x1bac80000 + 14468
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018cb0fd10 0x18ca6d000 + 666896
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018cb09bb0 0x18ca6d000 + 641968
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018cb091c0 0x18ca6d000 + 639424
5   Foundation                      0x000000018dde9fac 0x18dde2000 + 32684
6   Foundation                      0x000000018dde9e78 0x18dde2000 + 32376
7   UIKitCore                       0x000000018f62c38c 0x18e9ad000 + 13104012
8   Foundation                      0x000000018df5b2fc 0x18dde2000 + 1544956
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d86ccc00 0x1d86cb000 + 7168
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d86d5758 0x1d86cb000 + 42840

Thread 2 name:  JavaScriptCore bmalloc scavenger
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001baca90cc 0x1bac80000 + 168140
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d86d0434 0x1d86cb000 + 21556
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00000001a1690efc 0x1a1687000 + 40700
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000196f3adc8 0x195f6a000 + 16584136
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000196f3f20c 0x195f6a000 + 16601612
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000196f3ee18 0x195f6a000 + 16600600
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000196f40330 0x195f6a000 + 16606000
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d86ccc00 0x1d86cb000 + 7168
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d86d5758 0x1d86cb000 + 42840

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bac844fc 0x1bac80000 + 17660
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bac83884 0x1bac80000 + 14468
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018cb0fd10 0x18ca6d000 + 666896
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018cb09bb0 0x18ca6d000 + 641968
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018cb091c0 0x18ca6d000 + 639424
5   CFNetwork                       0x000000018d3e24b8 0x18d197000 + 2405560
6   Foundation                      0x000000018df5b2fc 0x18dde2000 + 1544956
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d86ccc00 0x1d86cb000 + 7168
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d86d5758 0x1d86cb000 + 42840

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d86d5744 0x1d86cb000 + 42820

Thread 5 name:  AVAudioSession Notify Thread
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bac844fc 0x1bac80000 + 17660
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bac83884 0x1bac80000 + 14468
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018cb0fd10 0x18ca6d000 + 666896
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018cb09bb0 0x18ca6d000 + 641968
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018cb091c0 0x18ca6d000 + 639424
5   AudioSession                    0x0000000194585f20 0x194579000 + 53024
6   AudioSession                    0x00000001945880d8 0x194579000 + 61656
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d86ccc00 0x1d86cb000 + 7168
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d86d5758 0x1d86cb000 + 42840

Thread 6 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.eventkit.eventstore.unsaved
Thread 6 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001baca9334 0x1bac80000 + 168756
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d86cdaa0 0x1d86cb000 + 10912
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000195f16b90 0x195e9f000 + 490384
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a16f6bb8 0x1a16e3000 + 80824
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a16e7ec8 0x1a16e3000 + 20168
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001a15f405c 0x1a15ed000 + 28764
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a16f5fa0 0x1a16e3000 + 77728
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a16f5f2c 0x1a16e3000 + 77612
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c783800 0x18c77f000 + 18432
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c792d2c 0x18c77f000 + 81196
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c792784 0x18c77f000 + 79748
11  EventKit                        0x0000000197e7a470 0x197d89000 + 988272
12  EventKit                        0x0000000197e79af0 0x197d89000 + 985840
13  EventKit                        0x0000000197e6b458 0x197d89000 + 926808
14  EventKit                        0x0000000197e6b21c 0x197d89000 + 926236
15  CordovaPlugins                  0x00000001025c9ab0 0x1025bc000 + 55984
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c781a54 0x18c77f000 + 10836
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c7837ec 0x18c77f000 + 18412
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c786938 0x18c77f000 + 31032
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c794fb0 0x18c77f000 + 90032
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c7957a8 0x18c77f000 + 92072
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d86ce768 0x1d86cb000 + 14184
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d86d574c 0x1d86cb000 + 42828

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d86d5744 0x1d86cb000 + 42820

Thread 8 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.eventkit.eventstore.dbchanged
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bacab1a8 0x1bac80000 + 176552
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c7a4fc8 0x18c77f000 + 155592
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c7a5a84 0x18c77f000 + 158340
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c792bbc 0x18c77f000 + 80828
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c792768 0x18c77f000 + 79720
5   EventKit                        0x0000000197e622a4 0x197d89000 + 889508
6   EventKit                        0x0000000197e612d0 0x197d89000 + 885456
7   EventKit                        0x0000000197e61e08 0x197d89000 + 888328
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c781a54 0x18c77f000 + 10836
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c7837ec 0x18c77f000 + 18412
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c78afd4 0x18c77f000 + 49108
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c78bbd0 0x18c77f000 + 52176
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c79648c 0x18c77f000 + 95372
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d86ce7a4 0x1d86cb000 + 14244
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d86d574c 0x1d86cb000 + 42828

Thread 9 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bacab1a8 0x1bac80000 + 176552
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c7a4fc8 0x18c77f000 + 155592
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c7a5a84 0x18c77f000 + 158340
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c792bbc 0x18c77f000 + 80828
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c792768 0x18c77f000 + 79720
5   EventKit                        0x0000000197e79920 0x197d89000 + 985376
6   EventKit                        0x0000000197e6b0ac 0x197d89000 + 925868
7   EventKit                        0x0000000197e6ae00 0x197d89000 + 925184
8   CordovaPlugins                  0x00000001025c825c 0x1025bc000 + 49756
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c781a54 0x18c77f000 + 10836
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c7837ec 0x18c77f000 + 18412
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c786938 0x18c77f000 + 31032
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c794fb0 0x18c77f000 + 90032
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c7957a8 0x18c77f000 + 92072
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d86ce768 0x1d86cb000 + 14184
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d86d574c 0x1d86cb000 + 42828

Thread 6 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x000000016d9f5e60   x5: 0x000000016d9f6400   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000004000
    x8: 0xb68d299acebd7a3d   x9: 0xb68d299ba3220a3d  x10: 0x0000000000000002  x11: 0x0000000000000003
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x0000000000000010  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x000000016d9f7000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x0000000000016063  x21: 0x000000016d9f70e0  x22: 0x00000002806c1100  x23: 0x0000000000000002
   x24: 0x0000000000000001  x25: 0x00000002806ed880  x26: 0x0000000000000000  x27: 0x00000001dbedd5ca
   x28: 0x0000000000000002   fp: 0x000000016d9f6370   lr: 0x00000001d86cdaa0
    sp: 0x000000016d9f6350   pc: 0x00000001baca9334 cpsr: 0x40001000
   esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault
```

Comment: This crash report is not symbolicated; you may have an easier time with identifiable symbols. [Here's an article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/adding-identifiable-symbol-names-to-a-crash-report) that may help you.

Comment: you need to dysymbolicate the crash log please check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67753702/6681300)