# App is crashing after successfully compile and build in Xcode

Tags: ios

There's a serious issue with my app. It was developed in late 2012 – but now I have to add some new SDKs.  I've added everything through CocoaPods.

Although it compiles and builds successfully, it's crashing just after it without showing me any error/warning messages.

I've tried to figure it out for a long time but still couldn't find a way.

Here's something that my Xcode is telling to me (after crash):

```
dyld_sim`dyld_fatal_error:
    0x1030c4000 <+0>: int3   
->  0x1030c4001 <+1>: nop
```

This is what I can see:

[image]

I've also set error break points:

[image]

But no luck.

I've put breakpoint in main.m and AppDelegate.m but it didn't stop over here.

This is **Build Settings - Architecture**:

[image]

What's the problem?

**Update:**

I got the following message when I run it on iPhone5 having 7.1.

> exited abnormally with signal 5: Trace/BPT trap: 5

**Update 2: Added Crash Log**

```
Incident Identifier: 86E3767B-D6FD-4E31-A10A-3D1A87E66DFB
CrashReporter Key:   bbd8c85f9242cf76be887456c573dc6db1b5d9ef
Hardware Model:      iPhone5,1
Process:             MY_APP [587]
Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/D0526AD1-A61F-4951-B1D5-E508D10A2591/MY_APP.app/MY_APP
Identifier:          com.myapp.MY_APP
Version:             1.0.9.2 (1.0.1)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-06-25 11:17:53.805 +0530
OS Version:          iOS 7.1.1 (11D201)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000000e7ffdefe
Triggered by Thread:  0

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: @rpath/XCTest.framework/XCTest
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/D0526AD1-A61F-4951-B1D5-E508D10A2591/MY_APP.app/MY_APP
  Reason: image not found
  Dyld Version: 324.1

Binary Images:
0x2be97000 - 0x2bebafff dyld armv7s  <4d05d388718832c99cdd4e74aeb07d51> /usr/lib/dyld
0x2f356000 - 0x2f458fff AVFoundation armv7s  <c88b12b244d13bbd9a8ab681956234e4> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x2fa79000 - 0x2fa99fff Accounts armv7s  <73b0639b81fe30d5b2b13628d3df2273> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x2fc1a000 - 0x2fc2bfff AssetsLibrary armv7s  <372ff89a2ede36aa85ce562f3e513f07> /System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/AssetsLibrary
0x30541000 - 0x30665fff CoreGraphics armv7s  <182ccc3a111d360eb5c1e58b4289afb3> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x30988000 - 0x309d7fff CoreLocation armv7s  <5d78705a46ab313fa21f1d5ed2f0ce3f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x30a0f000 - 0x30a8afff CoreMedia armv7s  <d68d0cf856f13ff7ab9418ccd671cd65> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x30b34000 - 0x30b8cfff CoreTelephony armv7s  <711db5ac808937b09143f43f11f06422> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x30b8d000 - 0x30c1dfff CoreText armv7s  <43e84c5a90fc36a984363965f2d8029b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x30ded000 - 0x30fd7fff Foundation armv7s  <b75ca4f9d9b739ef9b16e482db277849> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x31c27000 - 0x31cd2fff MessageUI armv7s  <42cf298919f134d888a001f1336c2550> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x31cd3000 - 0x31d36fff MobileCoreServices armv7s  <1a736ebbc93431c8943cdd93a0a0fdcb> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x3277e000 - 0x32786fff OpenGLES armv7s  <1c3e551d0a923b86940ad36a6e682463> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x32971000 - 0x32ab8fff QuartzCore armv7s  <741ee0338b1235aab1550f91a3956041> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x32b12000 - 0x32b54fff Security armv7s  <cd7187d315eb301e845cfae580ca905f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x32ca4000 - 0x32cf3fff SystemConfiguration armv7s  <82758c34b29a333bbdfe73e78361e0e1> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x32cf4000 - 0x32cf5fff Twitter armv7s  <b6adeefeb05639abb4140fa07a92e705> /System/Library/Frameworks/Twitter.framework/Twitter
0x32cf6000 - 0x33469fff UIKit armv7s  <f725ad0982673286911bff834295ec99> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x3a5d0000 - 0x3a61bfff libc++.1.dylib armv7s  <72615c78ae5f39dcbafa740d87035caf> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x3af0a000 - 0x3afa1fff libsqlite3.dylib armv7s  <584eaf4090783a64b8a33125a6a976bd> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x3b0f0000 - 0x3b0fcfff libz.1.dylib armv7s  <578def3dfb6e3180b5f9d0cdacfea7ab> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
```

Comment: What happens if you set as base sdk something a little older as 7?

Comment: I'm already running it with base sdk 7. Its crashing in iOS7 too. @ClaudioRedi

Comment: Before I used CocoaPods, everything was added via git (as submodules) but then I changed (and removed submodules) so that I could add new frameworks required. So I used CocoaPods to have all require frameworks in my app.

Comment: You don't see any useful information on console?

Comment: No, there's just nothing then I've added here.

Comment: Can you set breakpoints in your appdelegate (or view controller), to identify line where it crashes?

Comment: Was app working before adding new SDK? And I'm not saying if it was working on 2012, I'm asking if it run correctly when you started this new round of changes

Comment: Can you find the binary in `DerivedData` please and run `otool -L` on it to see what libraries/frameworks it's been linked against?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: @Yanchi It looks like a dynamic linking problem, so the program probably crashes before any of his code (even `main`!) is executed.  Also, he said "I've put breakpoint in main.m and AppDelegate.m but it didn't stop over here."

Comment: @NobodyNada, Yes you're right. I'm not able to find a breakpoint which stop for me. Also, I don't see any stack trace for this. This something terrible where I don't even know what's the real problem?

Comment: @Droppy, I don't know anything about, otool? Would you please tell me that how I can get and run it in my mac? Any link? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to build & run the app once I removed `OCMock`, `Specta` and `Expecta` frameworks from my project, and then, a full cleanup and cleaning of derived data before <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> make it works. Thanks everyone for your 2 cents :)

**Update:**

After doing this – I'm not able to debug my app. I should only allowed to run it in `release` mode. Otherwise its giving me this error.

> undefined symbols for architecture i386

Comment: What symbols are undefined?

Comment: All of the files – I've added in pod, are about to undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You say that you're on the IOS 7 SDK, however, your base SDK is set to 8.3

[image]

Maybe changing it to IOS 7 will fix the bug

Comment: Yes, I guess this is why I'm trying to running it in XCode 6.3? I can only see iOS 8.3 there. Even Clean + Build doesn't seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your main target is linking to XCTest.framework but failed.

1) Go to Project settings -> 2) Go to your apps main target -> other linker flags 3) remove '-framework XCTest' 4) make sure the 'other linker flags' field for your test target still contains '-framework XCTest'

2) check Images.xcassets, and other resources, in file inspector (right panel), look at 'target membership', check if you select the Tests target.

3) try search `XCTest` in your project and see what you have set.

Comment: I don't have any test cases in my app. It was previously added but I've removed it as I thought it was causing this issue. Also, for your 2nd point  – I don't have `Images.xcassets` folder in my app, as this is an old project. However when I search for `XCTest` in my app I found that few of the classes which I've added through pod seems to using it. Should I remove those files from Pod?

Comment: Yes, what I provided are things may use XCTest. We don't know your project settings, so the last resort would always be global search for XCTest and see what's been set. Hope you get luck!

Comment: @hagile it depends if you should remove those files if you are using it. Normally I would choose first try to modify the settings not to link XCTest.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But everything is linked through CocoaPods. And I'm not sure how do I do it manually?

Comment: Go to Pods － TARGETS －［Pods－${Project name}Tests－${name}］－Build Settings and see if you can modify it or link it. Google may help you. I am no expert of this. Sorry

Comment: Thanks buddy ! I'll get back to you if I need something.

Comment: based on the log, is missing XCTest linking caused the crash? If so, try to add XCTest linking for your pods. If it is the reversed way, just remove linking:) I just guess.

Comment: What I have googled: in Framework Search Paths，to add a new path，$(PLATFORM_DIR)/Developer/Library/Frameworks

Comment: Hey, thanks buddy! I'm going to remove everything which linked to XCTest framework and will update my pod.

Comment: Have you solved your problem? What's the reason? If it helps, consider accept one of the answers, this can help other people to quickly identify their problems.